# How can I email someone a git repository?

Tags: git

I have tried:

```
git archive HEAD --format=zip > archive.zip
```

:and then I email archive.zip and at the other end they unzip archive.zip into a folder. But when they try any git commands they find out that this does not produce a valid git repository

Comment: For others who find this: the reason git archive isn't right for the job is that it only packages up the work tree. It's for doing things like making a tarball of all your source, for distribution.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You could use **[`git bundle`](https://schacon.github.io/git/git-bundle.html)** and email one single file

See "[backing up project which uses git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046918/backing-up-project-which-uses-git/2047141#2047141)"

> A git bundle is just one file which can be very easily created and again imported as it can be treated like another remote.

Once received, you can clone it or fetch from that file.

As mentioned in "[Backup of github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo)", you will probably want for the first email to make your bundle with *all* branches:

```
$ git bundle create /tmp/foo-all --all
```

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25328/andreas) mentions in the comments, **[Scott Chacon](https://git-scm.com/about)** recently (March 2010) wrote a "cute" article on this topic in the [ProGit book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2):

[**Git's Little Bundle of Joy**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Bundling)

Comment: Thanks. I read this but it wasn't clear if all my history and branches are saved. Also does it allow me to merge both repositories at a later date?

Comment: @Zubair: yes, all the history is saved, contrary to `git archive`!

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out:
git init, and then :
git pull bundle.bdl master

Comment: @Zubair: unbundle it? You can simply clone it to get back a normal git repo. Or pull it in an empty repo. Which is, I see now, what you did ;)

Answer (score 8):

As previous answer said, [git bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle.html) is the way.

If you want to create a bundle from using only one branch (I prefer bundling only `main`) and sending over e-mail, you can do something as below:

```sh
git bundle create ~/mygitbackup.bundle main
```

Above will create a git bundle file in your home directory.