# How to move a git repository from 1 hard drive to another

Tags: git

I have a git repository in 1 hard drive. And I would like to relocate that to a different hard drive. What is the safest way to do that?
1. cp -r?
2. tar ball??
3. git clone (but what is the URI for that)?

I was concern if git repository contains absolute path so that 'mv' to a new directory will break git.

Thank you.

Comment: mv /path/to/old/dir /path/to/new/dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general solution is to use **[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784)** in order to:

- move just one (big) file
- clone it (from the bundle) in the destination: `git clone /my/new/drive/myrepo.bundle repo2`
- leave the first repo untouched (just in case)

That is not cessary in your scenario, but having one file saving everything can come in handy.

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem in reallocation a git repo ... just `mv` it.
Pay attention to surrounding jobs that could use it (maybe you gave `git-daemon` a path to it?). But the repository itself can safely be moved around.