# Is there any way to push and pull project from Flash drive instead of Git?

Tags: git, security, deployment, system-administration

I need to push a project from my local machine to a flash drive then pull this project to server which not connected to network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: initialise a bare repo on your flash drive and then use the [local protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_local_protocol) `file://` from your normal repo.

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin file://h/path/to/bare/repo.git
```

(Here, assuming h is the letter your flash drive is mounted)

Note: another option, if you do this only from time to time, is to [use a `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2670309/6309).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569757/how-to-use-usb-drive-as-remote

Comment: Agreed, this is a similar idea, minus the bundle option.