# Git is ignoring .git directories in subdirectories

Tags: git, backup

I'm using git as a backup tool and 'roaming profile' for my $HOME directory between laptop and desktop.

My problem is that under my $HOME I have a Development directory with multiple git projects I'm working on. Git will not allow me to add the subdirectories .git folders. So to commit to these projects I have to push the changes into my $HOME git repo, pull on laptop (where they were created and .git dir exsits) and commit.

I've read about submodules, but it's not really what I want. I just want the children .git folders to be treated like any old directory so I can move them around and back them up.

Has anyone done this or have an idea how I would?

Comment: imho, this is probably the wrong tool for the job. if you want to sync up your laptop and desktop, you might want to look into unison. if you want to version all of the work you do in $HOME, the easiest option is regular rsyncs, but of course that's not incremental. you'd need an incremental backup product, or you can hack something up using rsync and git

Comment: @Igor: I agree, generally. You don't necessarily have to rsync the git repos, though - you could easily script up a way to push/pull/update them in bulk, even if you decide submodules aren't the right way (though they could probably work for this purpose).

Comment: rsnapshot can do the incremental thing. honestly submodules is what you should be using. I'd just write a script to transfer all the repos. why do you want to version the git objects anyways? just to ease transfer? use something else. also this is NOT a SO question it should be on SUPERUSER. why do people ask all these non programming questions on SO.

Comment: 4 years later, I'm asking a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24198280/2533127.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. It's a bad idea because you are creating a versioned backup of a versioned repository. Just create a backup by rsync (you can still version the parent using git)

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally using git to sync some dot-files like .profile or .vimrc. To avoid problems like yours my git is located in $HOME/dot and the single files are symlinked in $HOME.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a script which would first backup every `.git` projects you have under your $HOME: it will produce *one* backup file (still under your $HOME)
See **[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784)** for more.

And then, you can add/update those backup (or "bundle") files to your main git repo (which contains all of your `$HOME` except the .git projects)

Finally, you can export all of your $HOME as one file with the same Git backup technique (`git bundle`).

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used [gibak](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/gibak-backup-system-introduction), a Git backup tool. Besides taking care of file attributes it also takes care of Git repositories inside your home directory.

One disclaimer though. I have used it for a while, but sometimes the backup became corrupt. I haven't investigated this, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that running applications constantly write data to your home directory. At some point the hashes mismatch and you have to do some smart things in order to get it fixed (or start a new backup).

At least give it a try, it may work for you. The problem I mentioned might also be caused by Git. Since I tried this 1.5 years ago, it might be fixed in the meantime.