# Moving Git Projects between computers

Tags: git, project, msysgit

I have a project that i use at two places(i dont use git server).

When i copy the project at second place i have to check-in all the files(but they have not changed), git shows me for example

```
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
-#Sat Mar 06 19:39:27 CET 2010
-eclipse.preferences.version=1
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
+#Sat Mar 06 19:39:27 CET 2010

+eclipse.preferences.version=1

+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled

+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6

+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6

+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error

+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error

+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
```

i did at both places the command
`git config --global core.autocrlf false`
but it doesnt help with this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a **[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784)** and see if the problem persist.
Plus, you will only have to move *one* file.

Answer (score 5):

Altough not answering your question - do not copy your git repo. Assuming you copy via USB memstick or something like that - create a third repo on the memstick (in 'bare' mode, preferrably), and sync your changes between the two computers via that repo.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) stuff between computers - if you have network access to git (ie, via ssh).

You can also use a third repo, either a public one (see [github](http://github.com/) and friends) or a private one (I really like [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) to manage my git "server") - this way you also get the benefit of having a backup.