# How to backup git server?

Tags: git

How to backup git server?
When git server is broken, How can I push my local repository to a new git server?

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

**[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784)**

That way:

- you have only one file to move to a backup server
- you actually can use this file as an "origin" repo from which you can pull/push data like a regular Git repo.

You will for the first backup create a full bundle:

```
$ git bundle create /tmp/foo-all --all
```

Comment: I think neither cloning, bundling or any other git command will get everything (for example the server side hooks). If you want to be sure to get everything a normal file based copy of the server repository directory would be needed.

Comment: @Zitrax I agree. hooks are not meant to be gotten or backed up within the same git archive, because they can be local to where the repo is used. I would back them up separately. But if those hooks are not an issue, a tar of the all repo would be enough indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You back it up like any other server, just mirror the files; git stores its metadata in files like anything else. If you move the repository to a new machine, you need to change your local repository's origin to point to it. In `.git/config` you'll find something like:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = SOMETHING
```

Change `SOMETHING` to the address of your new server

Comment: thanks a lot!
and How to set my backup files become a new git server and keep the git log before?