# Git: How to merge two folder pointing to the same repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I cloned a repository on a pc, and made some branches and commit. I was not able to push it (because of ssh authentication was not possible on pc). So I sent the file to another Pc (zip file), which could push the changes.

**Folder1**: contains the unziped files.

**Folder2**: contains a cloned version of the same repos, but without the changes in folder1.

I tried to push it but the server told me this error "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly".

I changed the remote url using `git config remote.origin.url=new_url` to use the git protocol instead of the http. But even then, I am unable to push the changes.

So how can I either push my changes (from **folder1**) to the server, or merge the changes from **folder1** to **folder2**, and be able to keep history?

thanks

**Edit:**

Based on @VonC's answer, I used these commands to merge correctly.

```
git bundle create bundle.bkp --all
git remote add temp-repos-to-merge ~/path/to/bundle.bkp
git fetch temp-repos-to-merge
git merge --no-ff temp-repos-to-merge/path/to/specific-branch
```

Comment: You can push from a PC with [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a zip, I would **bundle** `folder1` repo (see "[How to backup git server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870564/how-to-backup-git-server/2870908#2870908)"), which produces also one file.

Then I would go to `folder2` and pull from that bundle (after having added it as a remote)

See "[How to use git-bundle for keeping development in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635952/how-to-use-git-bundle-for-keeping-development-in-sync)" for a concrete example.

Comment: I have added the solution I used based on your answer, If someone ever wonders how I did it.