# Git: how to migrate all local repos to another machine?

Tags: git

I have code files from dozens of git repos in various subfolders under c:\code folder - 16Gb.

I want to migrate this folder to another computer. It's currently taking > 1 day to copy the entire folder to a USB drive, because it is around 650,000 small files.

Is there some script I can run to cleanup all of the repos in my c:\code folder?

Edit: all of the repos have a remote. I don't care about copying all branches. I only care about keeping the directory structure of the repos, i.e.

```
c:\code\github\NLog
c:\code\github\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
c:\code\myclient\DevOpsProject1\solution1
c:\code\myclient\DevOpsProject1\solution2
c:\code\myclient\DevOpsProject2\solutionx
etc
```

Comment: I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383408/6309) to address your edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was originally looking for:

```
find . -name .git -type d -execdir git clean -dxf \;
```

This cleaned up my 16Gb of files across all repositories down to 800Mb.
And then @VonC's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383408/32598)
(N.B remove v option from the below to be quieter)

```
tar cpvf code.tar code
```

and then on the destination machine:

```
tar xpvf code.tar
```

Whenever I would use git in the copied folders, I then kept getting errors:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository
```

So to fix that I had to "Take ownership" of the folder.
I'm on Windows, which meant Properties of the code folder -> Security  -> Advanced -> Owner -> Change. Even though "Local administrators" owned the folder, and I am a member of that group, I had to make myself the owner.

An additional hurdle was because I'm on a corporate machine I couldn't see the Security tab. [Here's the fix for that](https://superuser.com/a/1522619).

Comment: That should work indeed. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) to bundle each of the repositories [full history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870908/6309) into *one* file (per repository)

And you can zip the dozen of bundle into a giant tar file.

Result: only *one* (big) file to copy, and to untar.

You can then clone back your repositories from their respective bundle (cloning them from their bundle file).

---

I don't care about copying all branches. I only care about keeping the directory structure of the repos

The, an alternative approach is to simply `tar cpvf code.tar code` under `C:\`.
Copy the giant tar file to the target machine, and `tar xpvf code.tar`: the directory structure will be preserved.

A bit as [in here](https://serverfault.com/a/539169):

```
find . -name "*.git" -type d -exec tar -czf {}.tar.z {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

(Be careful with the `-exec rm` part: test it out first).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's a good approach. I have kicked off the `tar` command now, will see how long it takes. I was thinking of an alternative approach, with a `find` command which would find all git repos, and output the folder name and the remote origin url to a text file. And then on the other machine, I would do some other script which would git clone the repo back to the same folder. I don't need all of the compiled code and npm modules etc to be copied over.

Comment: @MattFrear Good idea. I have edited the answer to include a possible command following that approach.

Answer (score -2):

You clone only lasted commit from your remote repository like

> git clone --depth 1 https://url-of-your-repo

Comment: The question was about local repositories and migrating them to another drive, not cloning from origin repository