# Trying to fetch between two local repositories is failing?

Tags: git, fetch

I am a new user of GIT and just installed it in our workplace. I have my repository on my workstation and also my folder that is to be tracked.
Repository is `C:\MY_REPO` and the folder for doing code changes is `C:\MY_FOLDER`.

There are 3 files, F1, F2, F3 in the MY_FOLDER.

I made change to F2.

```
git add F2 
git commit
```

So now I assume that F2 - version 1 is in MY_REPO

I made another change to F2  - version 2, in MY\FOLDER followed by git add and git commit.

WHAT I WANT to do is to get F2 - version 1 from MY_REPO back into MY_FOLDER.

I cant get the `git fetch` command to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pull from another computer's repository in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131164/how-do-i-pull-from-another-computers-repository-in-git)

Comment: You need to configure your remote before you can fetch

Comment: Better target actually [Git pulling changes between two local repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775580/git-pulling-changes-between-two-local-repositories) the answer is the same though, configure a [`remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pulling changes between two local repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775580/git-pulling-changes-between-two-local-repositories)

Comment: I understand that I need to do a git remote. My remote/central repository is on C:\REPO_FOLDER.  My command then should be 'git remote add origin c:/REPO_FILDER/.git   ?