# How to pull a local repo in git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I need to pull a local repo to my new repo. Lets say i want to pull `original` to `duplicate`. I have seen solutions for it over here but there are some issues for both as explained below -

1. Add branch `original` to remote by using `git remote add original` and then pulling this remote repo. But i have got a repo with same name on remote repo that contains company logic that i wont to mess around with. So i cant use this method.
2. Using `git pull --help` i found that i can pull the repo using `git pull /path/to/repo's .git/file` but these both branches are of same project so they have same `.git` file.

Is there any other way i can do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775580/git-pulling-changes-between-two-local-repositories

Comment: ‘*Add branch `original` to remote by using `git remote add original`*’ adds a *remote*, not a *branch*. What does ‘*a repo with same name on remote repo*’ mean?!

Comment: @Biffen what exactly do you mean by adding to remote?

Comment: Do you know what a remote is? What about a branch?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a misunderstanding between the concepts `repo`, `branch` and `remote` here.

From my understanding you want to "pull a local branch into another local branch" (ie. "pull" a branch, not a repo).
`pull` is normally not terminology we use for local branches (a `pull` operation involves fetching something from a remote repo).

If this is what you want to do, there are two options:

- You can use e.g `git merge my_task_branch` to merge the `my_task_branch` into the current branch.
- You can use `git rebase master` to move the changes that you have made on the current branch, so that they are based on the latest change on the local `master` branch.

Both these options will ensure that the changes on the other branch (`my_task_branch`/`master` in the examples above) are made available in the current branch.

---

***Some terminology:***

**Repo:** A repo has one `.git` directory. If you have two repos, they (per definition) have two different `.git` directories, otherwise, they are the same repo.
      When you are saying "both branches are of the same project, so they have the same `.git` file", you mean that both branches are in the same repo.

**Branch:** A repo can have multiple branches. Each branch represents a history of changes which may be different. You can make some changes to one branch, commmit them. And then checkout another branch to
 make some other changes there.

**Remote:** A remote is a reference to another repo from/to which you can fetch/push changes.

**Pull:** A `git pull` operation has two parts. First, commits are fetched from some other remote repo (this can be done separately with `git fetch` command). Thereafter, some branch from the remote repo is merged into the current branch (`git merge` command)

**Local branch vs Remote branch:** You can create any number of local branches in your repo. But a local branch is different from a remote branch. You can create any number of local branches without impacting the remote repo in any way. The local branches only become visible in the remote repo if you `git push` those branches.