# Hardware Requirement for GIT server (RHEL linux)

Tags: linux, git, hardware, cpu, git-svn

I am migrating from SVN to GIT. Currently my SVN server hosts 30+ svn repos accessed by 1000+ developers 24x7. 
While migrating, I observed that it uses lot of cpu and makes the system slower. Also `git svn` command used 25+ gb space while final checkout.

**I want to know the hardware requirement for GIT server (RHEL linux).**
Is there any effect if repo size increases in GBs? Or requirement for future GIT maintenance operations?

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked at [git@vger.kernel.org](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#git). Are you using git over SSH or HTTP(s)?

Comment: i'm using both SSH and https (via apache).   Is there any other way for https, other than apache? sorry for deviation.

Comment: I can't give a good answer without more information. First, try to identify if the CPU spikes are due to real processing or I/O wait. If the CPU is blocking on I/O wait, you may solve it using faster disks. Compare the memory footprint from SSH ans HTTP. If the problem arises on HTTP only, the problem is with the underlying webserver. Many times it is more appropriate to update the question with new information instead of commenting (the comment system is not meant to be used as a forum or a chat room).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh, https through apache or NGiNX (all you need is to call the [`git-http-backend` smart http script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177044/6309)).
The requirements are fairly low because of the distributed nature of Git (the server is mainly the https or ssh one, there is no "git server" per se).

Adding [Gitolite for Authorization Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256) is a good idea.

The main limitation is about the size of the Git repos: they shouldn't be "big", in order to be cloned around easily (see "[What are the git limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-git-limits/984973#984973)").

Each Git repo is best used to represent one "component" (one coherent set of file represeting one artifact, being it a module, a program, a library, ...), and that differs from an SVN repo, which can includes many projects in the same referential.