# Git push using up too many resources and ended by host

Tags: git, resources, push

So I'm just now creating a repo for an old project.  In total I have 4.5 gigs of files so it's taking some time.  I'm on a shared hosting environment and my host limits processes that take up too much memory for too long a time.  Obviously, this process is taking a while, and it keeps getting ended by my host.

Is there a way I can easily chuck up the push for a single commit so I don't get rate limited?

This is also my first commit so I'm having trouble reverting all the files I added. Otherwise I would do it piece by piece.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is to create the bare repo locally and simply FTP it to the server.  That should work ok.

Answer (score 2):

In the same idea than [ScottS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51851/scotts)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984453/6309), I would create locally a [`bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle), in order to create *one* (giant) file.

FTP a single file is less error-prone than multiple files of a bare git repo.
(See "[How to synchronize two git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4860455/6309)" for a concrete example)

You can then clone from that bundle on the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have all your work in a single commit, you can `git push` your commits partially.

Using `git log` you can "walk" you history, checking some commits and pushing them to your remote. Lets say:

```
$ git log --oneline master
$ git checkout abcabc123123 # 10th commit in history
$ git push origin HEAD:master
$ git checkout bcdef145325 # 30th commit in history
$ git push origin HEAD:master
```

And so on...

How many commits your step will have to be will be a try&failure task - it depends on your commits' size.

If you don't have any history, maybe you can make individual commits for each file/folder (I think it would be a good idea to associate by filesize), `push` them as before told, and then squash all commits in a single one:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset acbacbad142 # hash of first commit
$ git commit --ammend
$ git push -f origin master
```

You rebase all your changes in a single commit with the `reset` + `commit --ammend`, and then `push -f` to rewrite the remote branch. Files (`blob`s, in git terms) will already be uploaded (even the `tree` will be), so it should not take big time.
As you are re-writing history, be sure no one clones/fetches from the remote in the time between you start making your short pushes and the time you push the squashed commit, to avoid conflicts.