# Using git to transfer data via usb stick between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, git, usb-drive

I am trying to use git for the first time in order to transport my bachelor thesis that I am currently writing between a Windows computer at work and a Linux computer at home. Because I don't have a server I would like to use a USB stick to store the shared repository. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251155/how-to-use-git-with-dropbox-and-a-usb-stick-thumbdrive) I understand that this should be possible.

On the Windows system I have created a working repository and the remote repository on the USB stick and pushed the working directory to the USB stick. This seems to be working fine.

On the Linux system I have cloned the repository, made some changes, added them and committed them. So far everything seems to be working fine. But when I try to push the changes back to the USB stick I get the following error message:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 264 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Operation not permitted
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To /media/usb-stick-sta/git/bachelor
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '/media/usb-stick-sta/git/bachelor'
```

In `/etc/fstab` I am using the following options to mount the USB stick: `noauto,user,uid=1000,gid=1000` so I own all the files and I have verified that this really is the case using `ls -l`.
Just to be sure I have also tried creating a file in that directory and removing it again, works without any problems.

One answers to another stackoverflow question (unfortunately I cannot find it again) suggested executing `chmod -R g+ws *` on the remote repository. It resulted in many error messages like (independent of whether I executed this as owner of the files or as root):

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘config’: Operation not permitted
```

Further research yielded the files might be immutable so I tried `chattr -i *` resulting in messages like:

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on config
```

Reading further I found that not all file systems support these attributes. The USB stick is formatted as FAT.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not store it on a private server? Bitbucket allows this for example.

Comment: @Bartlomiej Lewandowski unfortunately the internet connection in the flat where I am currently living is not reliable. And I am not sure about whether the company where I am writing the bachelor would allow me to use a service like that. I am not familiar with legal stuff like that. Things are a bit complicated cause I am doing a dual study (not sure about the English term)...

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski my mentor recommended me to use bundles when I told him I was having trouble with this approach. But that does not seem to be as comfortable as a simple push. And I would still like to know what went wrong. Thanks for the hint, anyway.

Comment: What Linux distribution do you use?

Comment: @axiac I am using Debian (not sure about the exact version and I am currently at work so I can't look it up but I think it's jessie, the desktop environment is cinnamon if that matters)

Comment: I'm using a similar setup but with a single computer running OSX and everything goes smooth. Try to create a new repository on the USB stick using Linux. Set the new repo as a remote for the local repo (on Linux) then try to push to it. If it works then you remove the old repo from the stick and use the new one. If it doesn't work then investigate the options of `mount` (they are probably correct if you can create and remove files manually on the stick) and of [`SELinux`](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux) (SELinux probably has a logfile or can be configured to create one).

Comment: @axiac thanks, I will try that as soon as I get home

Comment: @axiac yes, that works. On my linux computer I have created a new local repository with `git init` and a new remote repository with `git init --bare` on the USB stick. From the local repository I have pulled a bundle I have created at work and pushed it to the USB stick. For testing I have also created a second local repository and pulled, changed and pushed from there. Now the interesting question that I will answer tomorrow: Can I also pull and push from the Windows computer to the USB stick?

Comment: I'm looking forward to find out how this ends :-)

Comment: yes, it works. From the Windows system I have pulled, changed something and pushed it back to the USB stick. I still need to verify that it still works on my Linux system when I get home, after the first contact of the new repository with the Windows system. But so far it looks good :)

Comment: @axiac yes, it works. I have pulled, changed something and pushed from the Linux system, too. Thanks for your help. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Now the mystery is why it didn't work before? What differs in the two repositories?

Comment: @axiac good question. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If the repo isn't all that big, I would just pack it up into a tar or zip file and copy that to the USB stick and unpack it on the other machine. To help me with this I wrote the [genbackup](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/genbackup.sh) script. It creates a backup tarfile with the current date and the short hashtag in the filename.

If that is too cumbersome, keep track of the commits and do a `git format-patch` in the repo on one computer. Copy the patch files to the USB stick, and run `git am` on them on the other computer.

**Edit**: As for the error, it seems to me that this is the important part;

> remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Operation not permitted

Git wants to create a temporary file, and that fails with an EPERM error. Looking at the manual page for `git`, and searching for "temporary" gives only one hit: `git-unpack-file`. Unfortunately, the manual page for that program does not specify *where* it tries to create the temporary file. But after some googling it seems that `git` uses the `TMPDIR` environment variable. Check if that is set to someplace you have access to. If it doesn't exist set it to a sensible place and try again.

Comment: git bundle is much more convienient for offline transport of repository data than either of those options

Comment: It seems to me that `git-bundle` is about the same amount of work as the `format-patch`/`am` combination. And the advantage of making a zipfile or tarball is that it captures the complete `.git` directory, with `config`, hooks and `info/exclude`.

Comment: well, thanks... I suppose I will try to use bundles if push does not work. But I would still like to know what's going wrong here...

Comment: @jakun It could be yout TMPDIR setting. See edited answer.

Comment: @RolandSmith thank you very much. I will try that as soon as I am home.

Comment: @RolandSmith sorry, I just realized I have forgotten to answer you. TMPDIR was not set indeed. Unfortunately `mkdir ~/.tmp && export TMPDIR=~/.tmp` did not make a difference. However, I hope that the comment by axiac has solved it.