# Synchronising VSOnline with TFS on-premises

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there a way to synchronise Visual Studio Online with an on-premises TFS 2013 installation?
I would like to use Visual Studio Online as a source control backup.

As I am using Git, one solution I found is to use : --mirror.
But I am not satisfied with this solution because it relies on the developper and not the TFS administrator.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to synchronize two git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860166/how-to-synchronize-two-git-repositories)

You should be able to configure this no bother if both ends are git.