# How to run two game windows in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**What do I mean by two game windows in the Unity Editor?**

Well if one could basically be able to have two separate windows inside the  editor instead of being limited to having just one:

**Why would this be useful?**

It's mostly useful for **networking**. When testing a networked multiplayer game, normally one would have to wait a long time to create a standalone build to test and debug events, plus debugging errors on standalone is hard.

If I could just run two instances (one server/ one client) on the click of the play button I would save so much time.

**This is a game window btw**
https://i.gyazo.com/2aeb04f8a41f1508d262cf9a526311bc.png

Comment: (1) You absolutely can't do that.  What you do is simply this: build one version as an actual desktop app to your Mac (or PC).  Then use that one, and, the one "in the Editor".

Comment: (2) Note that for this reason, anyone who does multiplayer development, has two or three machines on their desk.  It's depressing but that's how it is.

Comment: (3) "plus debugging errors on standalone is hard"  I can help you there.  you ***absolutely must*** carefully set up systems that show you development messages, and so on, on the screen of the device.  (AND make sure you know how to watch the logs when it's playing on a device, google for it.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to test networking code, having multiple "game windows" open won't actually allow you to do that. If you have multiple copies of the project on your computer you can open multiple instances of unity. (unity puts a lock file in each project so you can't just open it twice using the same files)

Downside to this is that if you make changes in one project, you have to copy/redo that change in the copy of the project. But certainly faster than building and you can connect debuggers to both instances of unity

Comment: I gave it a shot and it seems to work, although I'm not quite sure what is the best solution to sync the projects together, github? https://i.gyazo.com/205b76642ebafd2e6f5602f927224dcb.gif

Comment: Yea any sort of version control system should work (git,svn, mercurial, etc).  It may be possible to do it just using a local git repo to sync locally without having to use github, this answer my help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860166/how-to-synchronize-two-git-repositories

Comment: Unless your client and server apps are going to just be two different copies of the same project, you can use robocopy and Unity command line arguments to automate the process of copying the project. Using this method, you can eliminate the need of a version control branch  for your "client" project copy:

Comment: SET projectPath=%cd%\..\CardGameMoba2
robocopy "..\CardGameMoba" "..\CardGameMoba2" /mir /R:0 /W:0
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Unity.exe" 2>nul | find /C "Unity.exe" > deleteme.txt
SET /p unityInstances=<deleteme.txt
IF %unityInstances% LSS 2 (
start "Launching Unity..." "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -projectPath "%projectPath%" -executeMethod Shortcuts.Play) ELSE (Echo 2 Unity IDEs already running, not launching new IDE.)
echo %unityInstances%
DEL deleteme.txt

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple directories and link "Assets", "Packages" and "ProjectSettings" from the origin to your copies. then all your changes are applied to all instances.

on windows: "mklink /d target source"
on mac: "ln -s source target"

you still have to apply a few settings in each instance ( like selected platform )

PS: make sure you modify your unique identifier in each copy instance to be able to act as different user/account. this should editor only and can help switch accounts to test different right/behavior

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of great assets on the unity asset store. Dual Play for example is free and does the job nicely! [Dual play](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/dual-play-multiplayer-testing-without-builds-164345)