# What tools exist for simple one-off sharing of a git repo?

Tags: git

I seem to often come across scenarios where I'd like to quickly give someone the means to clone a git repo from e.g. my laptop, and I'd like to perform this feat without running an SSH daemon, git daemon or any other kind of service requiring configuration (or even access control).

The simplest way I've come up with so far is to install the [adsf](http://stoneship.org/software/adsf/) command line web server gem for Ruby, make sure to run `git update-server-info` and then just run `adsf` in the directory I want to share. If I run it in the root of the repo, for example, I would then tell the other party to clone `http://<my_hostname_or_ip>:3000/.git`, or whatever port the server started on.

This works well enough, but does have the caveats of problems caused by concurrent access and the need to have Ruby and the particular gem installed.

What other tools or hacks do you use or know of that perform a similar function?

**edit:** to clarify, I'm looking for a solution like `hg serve`: ad hoc, quick and painless, requiring minimal setup and no persistent services.

Comment: Isn't just copying the repo as a directory enough for this scenario?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Copying the repo with what? It needs to go over the network after all. And that would only take care of the clone case, whereas the fetch case becomes necessary pretty quickly too.

Comment: What's wrong with just `git daemon`?

Comment: @ilkka email, ftp, whatever :) When I need to quickly share a repo I just pack it and send it.

Comment: Use a service like Dropbox or Ubuntu One and then share. If you have atleast one interest in your project, why not share via github or similar service?

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim nothing that I know of. How does it solve this particular problem? Please elaborate in an answer :)

Comment: @daganh example scenario: super sikrit proprietary code (so github/dropbox/ubuntu one are out) in a company network (so anonymous is ok) related to one-off demo being developed by 2 people (so need to share does exist but not for long).

Comment: @Ilkka Dropbox is a completely encrypted solution that allows private sharing. Its a breeze to setup and will allow alot of freedom for you and your friend. If its that secret, then why not go through the trouble of ssh.

Comment: @daganh it's a matter of liabilities and policy as much as of technology.

Comment: daganh : As the recent dropbox fiascos show, the "cloud" is not all that trustworthy. If it's *your* data and *you* want to share it, using a 3rd party service should be a last resort.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run this from somewhere.

```
git daemon --export-all --base-path=/tmp --port=9090 /tmp/foo/.git
```

`/tmp/foo/.git` is the directory you want to expose.

Then you can clone it somewhere else like so

```
git clone git://localhost:9090/foo testdir
```

And you'll get the repository in testdir.

Kill the server with `^C` when you're done. It can also take options on what services to enable/disable. `git help daemon` for more info. I think it's much more straightforward than `adsf`.

Comment: +1: if there is a network connexion between the two, and if the port isn't blocked by the company proxy, it is the right solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for :) Git daemon just stumped me at first, seemingly not being geared so much toward this scenario.

Comment: Well, that's why I asked you what was wrong with that. It seemed perfect for the job. :)

Comment: I have `git config --global alias.serve 'daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose'`. It makes daemon easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

For a clone shared between two user for a brief period of time, I would rather:

- create only one file through [**`git bundle`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository)
- mail or copy that one file on the other developer workstation.

That would work even if there is no newtwork connexion between the two users.

Comment: +1. You would need a network connection to mail the file but I didn't know about `bundle`. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Noufal: by "network connexion", I meant two computers on the same network. Through mail, you can be on completely different network, which don't see each other.

Comment: I figured. I was just nitpicking. :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `bundle` either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually running Apache, so it would be as simple as:

```
ln -s . ~/public_html/my_gift_repo
```

Comment: This is fine and good, but I generally don't want to run HTTP servers on machines that aren't.