# git clone vs copy paste, what's the difference?

Tags: git, copy-paste, git-clone

as stated in the subject

note: the git clone i mean is the git clone without any option, the one which is performed by doing "git clone /C:/my_origin_folder"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This answer of mine regarding backup should give you some answer on clone vs copy: [Moving a git repo to a second computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851966/moving-a-git-repo-to-a-second-computer/5852283#5852283)

Main differences:

1. When you clone, you get remote `origin` setup pointing to original repo, so that you can push to it.
2. You don't get hooks and reflog ( and also old objects) and other remotes when you clone but you do when you copy

Note that when you clone with a folder path, the differences change subtly, as the objects  and refs are usually just copied / hardlinked ( equivalent of `--local` which is the default with local folder paths)

Answer (score 4):

When you use git clone instead of copy paste, the original repository will be the origin.

Besides, when cloning on the same machine you can use --local to make it faster. From the manual page:

> --local, -l
>
> When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag bypasses the normal "git aware" transport mechanism and clones the repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything under objects and refs directories. The files under .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked to save space when possible....

Comment: When you use a local path to clone, it is by default using `--local`