# Can Git repos be moved indiscriminately?

Tags: git

Say I have a single sub-directory `gits` containing all my mirrors of various repos and I want to segment them into logical areas.

Is it possible to just move the repo directories to another location, along the lines of:

```
gits                     gits          dodgy-gits
 |- python                |- python     |- perl
 |- csharp     --->       |- csharp     |- c++
 |- perl
 |- c++
```

Or is there anything in the Git metadata  that will make this problematic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Git repository directory location.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384928/change-git-repository-directory-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the repos where you want without any problem.

All the relevant data is contained in the `.git` subfolder and there are no absolute paths to care about.