# How to upload in an Existing Repository?

Tags: github

I have a repository. I pushed files from a folder. Now I don't want to create new Repository. But I want to push files from a new Folder. The folders are almost same. How can I do this with command?

Comment: I think you are looking for this - [This has answer you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384928/change-git-repository-directory-location)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have the repository created, you can do the following.

```
cd newfolder
git clone <link-to-clone-from>
```

Then copy the files to new folder. Check git status -s to see a summary of changed files in new folder after you copy files. Using git diff or beyondcompare can show you the exact changes that you are about to commit next. If everything looks fine, continue with the next steps

```
git add -a 

git commit -m "your commit message"

git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two folders:

```
- Old repo folder
  - .git
  - My old folders
  - My old files.
- New repo folder
  - My new folders
  - My new files.
```

And you want to replace all stuff in the remote repo from the old repo folder with the new repo folder.

---

To do that:

- First, delete all content except the folder: `.git` in the `Old repo folder`.
- Then, copy everything except the folder: `.git` from the `New repo folder` to the `Old repo folder`
- And run commands in the `Old repo folder`:

```sh
$ git status
```

To get if everything is fine. Git will detect that you have replaced a lot of files and deleted many of them. Check the output.

```sh
$ git add . && git commit -m "Replace with new content"
```

```sh
$ git push
```

And this will save your changes and send it to remote server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have one repo. I mentioned it in first sentence.