# git change in folder structure of source code

Tags: git

**I am using git and here is the situation :**

[image]

There is a branch feature/API*** . The source code is under the folder "Code/" as can be seen in the pic. I am trying to get rid of the folder 'code/' . I have tried to move the source Code including .git files out from the 'code/' folder and then delete 'code/'. But 'git status .' doesn't show me the deleted folder i.e. 'code/'. **How do I safely move my source Code out of the 'Code/' folder and get rid of 'Code/' folder.** The issue is when I do a 'git clone' , I get my code into sub-folders and the root folder is 'code/'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Git repository directory location.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384928/change-git-repository-directory-location)

Comment: My question is completely different.

Comment: Is your `.git` was inside the `code` folder ? If so, your folder changes will bas no effect on git