# Moving git repos to other computer

Tags: git, repo

I tried (like described here [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851966/moving-a-git-repo-to-a-second-computer))

to copy my whole repos to a new computer.

But now, it seems that git sees everything in the new directory as changed and want's me to commit these local changes.

There should be no local changes currently, since i just only copied the directories over to the new computer.

How can i bring all the repo-directories in sync again?

Comment: How did you proceed? Clone? Bundle? Tell us what commands you used if you want useful answers.

Comment: (and their outputs)

Comment: Different OS, perhaps? Different line endings expected in the files?

Comment: @RomainValeri  I just copied the directories. So no special commands

Comment: @J.Titus Different OS: yes. I copied from windows to a linux system

Comment: "Everything new" sounds like a file permission change detected for every file, or line endings, maybe? But still difficult to say without more detailed info.

Comment: @RomainValeri How can i find out more details? I had a look into the diffs, but it shows nothing. So i would suspect it is something outside the file like file permission or something. Are file permissions versioned with git? If so, this may be because of the copy from windows to linux.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to "sync" now.

Since i had no real local changes changes, i did the following:

First, i reset the local changes:

find -name .git -execdir git reset --hard ;

And then, did a pull:

find -name .git -execdir git pull ;