# Version Control from a different age

Tags: version-control

At my work I'm on a separate network to my colleague due to clearance reasons, and we both need to share code. I am wondering what the best versioning system would be? There's got to be something better than having project1.zip, project2.zip , etc - but something not as expansive as git or hg.

Comment: Don't you think you should be asking your security officer this question? Mightn't even emailing a .zip file be a security violation?

Answer (score 2):

I would still recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/), as it allows to:

- [make a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817095/what-tools-exist-for-simple-one-off-sharing-of-a-git-repo/5817461#5817461) (only one file, and it can be an *incremental* bundle)
- [mail that bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784) to your colleague (meaning it will work even if your separate networks have *no other way* to communicate)

The idea is to exchange one file (from which you can pull any new history bundled in it).
And Git is very cheap for creating and adding a repo when an existing code base is already there.

That being said, any communication procedure will have to be approved by your employer: don't bypass any security measure ;)