# How does one push from NTFS (desktop) to FAT32 (usb)?

Tags: git, filesystems

I would like to use my USB stick for transferring branches to and from work/home computers (due to network restrictions).

However, when I push to the usb (FAT32) from my desktop (NTFS), I get various errors (error: packfile, fatal: bad object, etc.). The usb git repo was initialised with the "bare" option.

I am assuming that this has something to do with filesystems because that's what my web searches have suggested. I also tried to pull/push to a different location on my desktop, and that does not throw any errors.

Does anyone know how I can get round this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: may be you should also try different usb stick. I had never encounter problem between NTFS and FAT32 when transferring data.

Comment: Seconded. Git doesn't use any special filesystem attributes, it's all contained inside the files. Could you try with a different stick?

Comment: I tried my phone (htc android) and that produced the same errors. It's FAT32 too, but given your comments, I assume that makes no difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- push to a [**bundle**, ie to a local unique file representing your bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784).
- copy that one (updated) bundle file on your USB key

(you can even try to push directly to a bundle on your USB key)

The idea is to sidestep completely the issue of a different file system by pushing / pull to/from a unique file easy to copy around.

For mobility/backup purpose, I always have preferred the bundle solution anyway, as in the question "[How two laptops can git push/pull to each other with no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948354/how-two-laptops-can-git-push-pull-to-each-other-with-no-internet/5948984#5948984)".

Comment: With my very limited knowledge, and testing, this seems to be working. Thanks!