# Is Rsyncing git repo good enough backup solution?

Tags: git, backup, rsync

I often backup my laptop to an external hard drive. Is rsyncing git repos over good enough backup solution or are there any problems with this method?

Comment: you could use something like bitbucket if you need private repos and use that as a backup...

Comment: @three I don't trust third parties when it comes to my source code

Comment: well, then just rsync it to a local hard drive. Make sure in case of fire that external hard drive is not destroyed too.

Comment: By the way see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713101/rsync-exclude-according-to-gitignore-like-cvs-exclude for information on handling ignored files like build products.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rsync` is a good solution for this.  It may be a good idea to run `git gc` and `git repack` (neither with any arguments) before doing your backup; this may significantly reduce the number of files, and increase the chance of the data not changing too much by next time.  Neither will lose any data.

See [Git Best Practices (by Seth Robertson)](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/#backups) for a write-up of why doing this with git isn't such a good solution.

Comment: Big advantage of using `rsync` (or `tar` or whatever) vs. `git clone`: `clone` doesn't clone local things like stashes.

Comment: Link moved to https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/#backups

Answer (score 3):

rsync is interesting if you really want to backup everything (including hooks and private files).
However:

- it doesn't guarantee the **integrity** of your repo once sync'ed (ie is git still working from the rsync'ed repo?)
- it has a higher probability of **data corruption** (you have to save many many files)

A nicer (and cleaner) solution would be to use **[git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784)** (which is essentially a bar repo seen as *one* file).
You update your local bundle, and save rsync it to your remote media.
Except that, this time, you only "rsync" (actually a simple copy is enough) ***one file***.
And you can directly clone or pull from that one file, that bundle.

Comment: @Ale the bundle can be incremental: that is still one file, but much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I have a repo I keep on hosting that I push to. If I want to work somewhere I clone it, push changes back when I'm done.

You could rsync it too, but I found it easier to clone a repo out and then use it as my main dev spot. I think using one tool might be easier, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: He was asking about making a backup, not doing work with the repo!?