# rsync exclude according to .gitignore & .hgignore & svn:ignore like --filter=:C

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, rsync

Rsync includes a nifty option `--cvs-exclude` to “ignore files in the same way CVS does”, but CVS has been obsolete for years. Is there any way to make it also exclude files which would be ignored by modern version control systems (Git, Mercurial, Subversion)?

For example, I have lots of Maven projects checked out from GitHub. Typically they include a `.gitignore` listing at least `target`, the default Maven build directory (which may be present at top level or in submodules). Since the contents of these directories are entirely disposable, and they can be far larger than source code, I would like to exclude them when using rsync for backups.

Of course I can explicitly `--exclude=target/` but that will accidentally suppress unrelated directories that just happen to be named `target` and are not supposed to be ignored.

And I could supply a complete list of absolute paths for all file names and patterns mentioned in any `.gitignore`, `.hgignore`, or `svn:ignore` property on my disk, but this would be a huge list that would have to be produced by some sort of script.

Since rsync has no built-in support for VCS checkouts other than CVS, is there any good trick for feeding it their ignore patterns? Or some kind of callback system whereby a user script can be asked whether a given file/directory should be included or not?

*Update*: `--filter=':- .gitignore'` as suggested by LordJavac seems to work as well for Git as `--filter=:C` does for CVS, at least on the examples I have found, though it is unclear if the syntax is an exact match. `--filter=':- .hgignore'` does not work very well for Mercurial; e.g. an `.hgignore` containing a line like `^target$` (the Mercurial equivalent of Git `/target/`) is not recognized by rsync as a regular expression. And nothing seems to work for Subversion, for which you would have to parse `.svn/dir-prop-base` for a 1.6 or earlier working copy, and throw up your hands in dismay for a 1.7 or later working copy.

Comment: Sounds a bit like it would be a good idea to submit a patch for rsync that adds support for .gitignore, .hgignore, etc.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I filed https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9744 as a starting point.

Comment: just a note for others, the .gitignore needs to be in the folder hierarchy being rysnc'd, not in the directory the command is being executed

Comment: What does `:-` mean exactly? What does the colon mean? What the dash?

Comment: Git now has a `check-ignore` subcommand that can deal with the hard work of parsing the various "ignore" files, if you want to go with the "generate a list of all non-ignored" files option. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664610/107294) gives details of how to do that.

Comment: @David The `:` represents `dir-merge` (useful if you have `.gitignore` files deep in the folder tree) and the `-` represents `exclude` (filter can also include).

Answer (score 174):

As mentioned by luksan, you can do this with the `--filter` switch to `rsync`. I achieved this with `--filter=':- .gitignore'` (there's a space before ".gitignore") which tells `rsync` to do a directory merge with `.gitignore` files and have them exclude per git's rules. You may also want to add your global ignore file, if you have one. To make it easier to use, I created an alias to `rsync` which included the filter.

Comment: A good start, though I hesitate to “accept” this answer as it only covers Git.

Comment: A more verbose version which also excludes .git files: `--exclude='/.git' --filter="dir-merge,- .gitignore"`

Comment: I have something like this now: `rsync -rvv --exclude='.git*' --exclude='/rsync-to-dev.sh' --filter='dir-merge,-n /.gitignore' $DIR/ development.foobar.com:~/test/` .. but although it says `[sender] hiding file .gitignore because of pattern .git*`, the file still is sent to the desintation

Comment: If you also want to use `--delete` option, here is the working command line: `rsync --delete-after --filter=":e- .gitignore" --filter "- .git/" -v -a ...`. This took me a while... `e` in filter and `--delete-after` are both important.  I suggest reading the "PER-DIRECTORY RULES AND DELETE" chapter of `rsync` man page.

Comment: @VasyaNovikov,why not `--exclude='/.git' --filter="dir-merge,+ .gitignore"`?`+` means includes files listed in `.gitignore`.

Comment: To sync deletes as well as adds & updates, you can simply add `--delete-after` to @VasiliNovikov's version of the command. (This seems equivalent to @dboliton's version of the command, except @db uses :e which i think excludes the .gitignore files from being copied, which is not what I wanted.)

Comment: Does this assume running `rsync` from the directoy with the `.gitignore` in it? Or does it pull ot from the dir syncs from? I guess I have to put in the full path to .gitignore to be save?

Comment: @dbolotin Why is the `:e` important when also wanting to delete-after?

Answer (score 33):

After the hours of research I have found exactly what I need: to sync the destination folder with the source folder (also deleting files in the destination if they were deleted in the source), and not to copy to the destination the files that are ignored by `.gitignore`, **but also not to delete this files in the destination**:

```sh
rsync -vhra /source/project/ /destination/project/ --include='**.gitignore' --exclude='/.git' --filter=':- .gitignore' --delete-after
```

In other words, this command **completely ignores files from .gitignore, both in source and in the destination**.
You can omit `--exclude='/.git'` part if want to copy the `.git` folder too.

You **MUST** copy `.gitignore` files from the source. If you will use LordJavac's command, the `.gitignore` will not be copied.
And if you create a file in the destination folder, that should be ignored by `.gitignore`, this file will be deleted despite `.gitignore`.
This is because you don't have `.gitignore`-files in the destination.
But if you will have these files, the files described in the `.gitignore` will not be deleted, they will be ignored, just expected.

Comment: This solution is especially perfect for project that uses multiple `.gitignore` scatter around their directory, which is most of the modern git structure. Glad I scroll down to here

Comment: Sorry but this does not work as expected because rsync is not able to properly ready gitignore files and gets confused by what it find there. Example, if you have `foo/*` inside `.gitigore`, rsync with fail to sync `src/foo/.*` even that is not part of the git ignore patterns.

Comment: I omitted the exclude for .git but it still does not copy that directory..
EDIT: solved by  `--include '.git'`

Comment: Since it's non-obvious, might be worth noting that `':- .gitignore'` means dir-merge (`:`), exclude patterns (`-`) from the file `.gitignore`. "dir-merge" is short for "per-directory merge", which means "rsync will scan every directory that it traverses for the named file, merging its contents when the file exists into the current list of inherited rules."

In my case, I only have one `.gitignore`, and it's in a parent directory, so the correct option for me is: `--filter='.- ../.gitignore'`, which is a "single-instance" (`.`) merge.

Comment: On second thoughts I could just run the original command from the parent directory and adjust <src>. Comment left as guide to others.

Comment: This shorter version worked for me too: `rsync -vhr /source/project/ /destination/project/ --filter=":- .gitignore" --exclude=".git"`

Comment: It seems to fail double inversion through exclusion of entries within `.gitignore`. Thinks like `!/excluded/dir` will not work. Tested with `*` as first line (ignore everything), followed by exclusions of that. Expecting `rsync` to properly include the reverted entries in my `.gitignore`, that doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `git ls-files` to build the list of files excluded by the repository's `.gitignore` files.
[https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree)

Options:

- `--exclude-standard` Consider all `.gitignore` files.
- `-o` Don't ignore unstaged changes.
- `-i` Only output ignored files.
- `--directory` Only output the directory path if the entire directory is ignored.

The only thing I left to ignore was `.git`.

```
rsync -azP --exclude=.git --exclude=`git -C <SRC> ls-files --exclude-standard -oi --directory` <SRC> <DEST>
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  it excludes the first file from the git subcommand and then treats the rest as part of the SRC list.  this works:  `rsync -azP --exclude-from="$(git -C SRC ls-files --exclude-standard -oi --directory > /tmp/excludes; echo /tmp/excludes)" SRC  DEST`

Comment: This is the only method that works if you have both exclude *and include* lines in your `.gitignore` (i.e. lines that start with `!`). It also rsyncs files that you `--force` added to your repo, which is usually a good thing.

Comment: Indeed this answer does NOT WORK, so I ended up writing one that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059607/99834

Answer (score 13):

### 2018 solution [confirmed](https://github.com/pycontribs/rtox/blob/master/rtox/rtox.py#L69)

```
rsync -ah --delete 
    --include .git --exclude-from="$(git -C SRC ls-files \
        --exclude-standard -oi --directory >.git/ignores.tmp && \
        echo .git/ignores.tmp')" \
    SRC DST
```

Details: `--exclude-from` is mandatory instead of --exclude because likely case that exclude list would not be parsed as an argument. Exclude from requires a file and cannot work with pipes.

Current solution saves the exclude file inside the .git folder in order to assure it will not affect `git status` while keeping it self contained. If you want you are welcome to use /tmp.

Comment: This looks like it will work if you have a _particular_ Git repository you want to synchronize—the `SRC` here—but not for the original problem I stated, which is a sprawling directory with thousands of Git repositories as subdirectories at various depths, many of which have idiosyncratic `.gitignore`s.

Comment: If you are using a shell with support for process substitution (bash, zsh, etc.) you can use `--exclude-from=<(git -C SRC ls-files --exclude-standard -oi --directory)`

Answer (score 9):

how about `rsync --exclude-from='path/.gitignore' --exclude-from='path/myignore.txt' source destination`?
It worked for me.
I believe you can have more `--exclude-from` parameters too.

Comment: This will work insofar as your `.gitignore` files happen to use a syntax compatible with `rsync`.

Comment: @JesseGlick is right, rsync is not able to parse .gitignore files, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059607/99834 workround.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`rsync -azP --delete --filter=":- .gitignore" <SRC> <DEST>`

It can copy all files to remote directory excluding files in '.gitignore', and delete files not in your current directory.

Answer (score 3):

I had a number of very large `.gitignore` files and none of the "pure rsync" solutions worked for me. I wrote this [rsync wrapper script](https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-utils/blob/master/bin/gsync), it fully respects `.gitignore` rules (include `!`-style exceptions and `.gitignore` files in subdirectories) and has worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Trying this via `locate -0e .gitignore | (while read -d '' x; do process_git_ignore "$x"; done)`, but has a lot of issues. Files in the same directory as `.gitignore` not correctly separated from the directory name with `/`. Blank lines and comments misinterpreted. Chokes on `.gitignore` files in paths with spaces (never mind the fiendish `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.4/spec/fixtures/custom 'path/.gitignore` from the `vagrant` package for Ubuntu). Perhaps better done as a Perl script.

Comment: @JesseGlick I'm not sure why you're calling the function within the script. it's intended to be used as a drop-in replacement for `rsync`, for the specific reason that handling quoting/whitespace is such a pain. If you have an example of a `gsync` command line that is failing, and the `.gitignore` files associated with it, I would be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: I need to `rsync` an entire filesystem, with various Git repositories scattered around it. Perhaps your script works fine for the case of synchronizing a _single_ repository.

Comment: yes, definitely. sorry I did not make that clear. With this script, you'd have to invoke it once per git repo, from within the repo directory.

Answer (score 3):

For **mercurial** you might use

```
hg status -i | sed 's/^I //' > /tmp/tmpfile.txt
```

to collect the list of files which are NOT under mercurial control because of *.hgignore* restrictions
and then run

```
rsync -avm --exclude-from=/tmp/tmpfile.txt --delete source_dir/ target_dir/
```

to rsync all files except the ignored ones.
Notice **-m** flag in rsync that will exclude empty directories from syncing because *hg status -i* would only list excluded files, not dirs

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MERGE-FILES FILTER RULES section in rsync(1).

It looks like it's possible to create a rsync --filter rule that will include .gitignore files as traverses the directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Per the `rsync` man page, in addition to the standard list of file patterns:

> files listed in a $HOME/.cvsignore are added to the list and any files listed in the CVSIGNORE environment variable

So, my $HOME/.cvsignore file looks like this:

```
.git/
.sass-cache/
```

to exclude .git and the files generated by [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: To the contrary, I definitely want to include `.git/` directories, perhaps even more strongly than the working copy. What I want to exclude are build products.

Comment: Also, this setting is not portable. It's per-user, not per-project.

Comment: @JesseGlick I second you about keeping .git/ dirs included. Git being a distributed SCM, it's important to backup the whole local repository.

Comment: 1/ The sentence from the `rsync` man page quoted in this answer describes the `--cvs-exclude` option, so you have to use it explicitly.
2/ You may create `.cvsignore` files in any directory to have project-specific ignores, those are read as well.
3/ `.git` is already ignored when you use `--cvs-exclude`, according to the manual, so having it in `$HOME/.cvsignore` seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives:

`git ls-files -zi --exclude-standard |rsync -0 --exclude-from=- ...`

`git ls-files -zi --exclude-per-directory=".gitignore" |...`

(rsync only partly understands .gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating exclude filters, you can use `git ls-files` to select each file to rsync:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! $# -eq 2 ]] ; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) <local source> <rsync destination>"
    exit 1
fi

cd $1
versioned=$(git ls-files --exclude-standard)
rsync --verbose --links --times --relative --protect-args ${versioned} $2
```

This works even though `git ls-files` returns newline separated paths. Probably won't work if you have versioned files with spaces in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```
rsync -r --info=progress2 --filter=':- .gitignore' SOURCE DEST/
```

Parameters meaning:

`-r`: recursive

`--info=...`: show progress

`--filter=...`: exclude by the rules listed on the .gitignore file