# Convert .gitignore to rsync merge filter include file? (with sed or awk)

Tags: git, sed, awk, rsync

I tried using rsync `--filter=':+ .gitignore'`  ([-/exclude works but not include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373763/790359)) to no avail.

Basically i just want to include the .ignore file in a script and upload everything in it with rsync to the remote.

If anyone would have the skills to sed or awk .gitignore  into  a file suitable for include with `--filter='merge file'`  etc it would me much appreciated!

Or alternatively a way just to make rsync understand .gitignore for inclusion.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html 'PATTERN FORMAT'

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch

https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob_plain;f=wildtest.txt;hb=HEAD

https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob_plain;f=wildtest.c;hb=HEAD

Some Issues are in rsync `bla/` means just that dir, `bla/*` means just the files in that dir, `bla/**` means just everything under that dir (including subdirs)  and `bla/***` finally means bla and all it's contents but all git might have is `bla/`

But [exclude rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373763/790359) seem compatible.

Comment: Or just rsync the .git directory itself and forget about the working directory?

Comment: (If that is not sufficient, please explain why)

Comment: @Arafangion Sorry maybe my question is unclear I want to get all the entries in .gitignore and 'include' them in an rsync so rsync uploads the ignored files in my working tree to wherever.  The git object database doesn't have those files.

Comment: sabgenton: Consider trying to explicitly add the '.*' files, and see the rsync man page for the --include option.  Additionally, the .gitignore file is not normally itself excluded by git, but it's a "dot file", so many unix scripts may ignore it.

Comment: Ultimately I want a script say `git rsync-ignored` that will understand every ignore list it comes across and uploads it to orign or someware I chose. I don't want to do it explicitly in the long run and I don't know sed or awk.

Comment: sabgenton: But it won't solve your problem because git does *not* ignore the .gitignore file, however you say that rsync is ignoring it?  Clearly, there is different behaviour. Unless...  Is your .gitignore file explicitly ignoring itself?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this: (Again, untested)

```
git ls-files -oz | rsync --include-from=- --from0
```

Comment: Ah now your talking!! I have to go but will check this concept out :D this lets git handle understanding of .gitignore good thinking :)

Comment: `discarding over-long filter`  :(, will see if rsync can lift this restriction later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1446609/790359 says git can not accurately pipe ignore lists :(. So if rsync can't read gitignore only converting the .gitignore file to rsync rules is left.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [gsync](https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-utils/blob/master/bin/gsync) rather than `rsync`. I wrote it because:

I have a project with the following characteristics:

- The `.gitignore` in the root directory is 60+ lines long
- There are 4 subdirectories that have with their own `.gitignore`
- Some `.gitignore` files include lines with `!`-style exceptions

I tried the methods in other answers. Some were promising but ultimately I hit the `discarding over-long filter` error. So I wrote [gsync](https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-utils/blob/master/bin/gsync) as a wrapper script for `rsync` to properly handle `.gitignore` files (in subdirs, with support for `!`-style exceptions. I think you'll find it helpful.