# filtering of files and paths from gitignore

Tags: c#, git, gitignore

I would like to find all file paths that are *not* filtered by a .gitignore (or any nested .gitignore files within sub-directories) using C#. This is similar to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981583/php-filtering-files-and-paths-according-gitignore) with regard to PHP. I'm wondering if someone knows if this code had already been made available (in C#) somewhere online.

UPDATE: To answer what I want this for, it is so I can run my own little periodic backup of my source files for certain projects (zipping the result), for added peace of mind. The hard part is getting a robust .gitignore parser to get the filtered file paths (and exclude the others), without wanting to become too embroiled in learning that spec if someone else already has done it for me.

Comment: Please post an attempt with a specific problem that you're having, not a "how can I do this" question.

Comment: Also, it looks like the PHP version you linked would be easily transferable to C# anyway.

Comment: I would view it as a disappointment if SO is considered to not be appropriate for asking if there is already an online code solution available for a problem like this. I would have some fun learning the full .ignore spec to roll my solution, but I don't have the time to take some days if such a solution already exists. I gave it a 80% chance one of you guys would do this, oh well. I like the SO of some years ago, when it was less up tight and anxious about a question like this (asking if someone knows of an already made source of code for a given solution).

Comment: As for searching for this myself online, search engines are terrible at this, because the keyword 'gitignore' just includes any and every project that has that file name in it. So that makes this a hard topic to google or search github on, etc.

Comment: If you review the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically the [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section, #4 clearly states that questions recommending a library are off topic, because they attract opinionated answers and spam. They also become out of date quickly due to new libraries being created so often. If you don't like this, you're more than welcome to bring it up on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thank you Dave. I have never been active on Meta, but on this point, I would advocate at least for a distinguishment between "What's the best software that ..." from "Is there *any* online source code that solves [xyz *very* particular problem" (note that's not asking for 'the best' of those). One of the worse things a dev can do besides writing bad code is re-writing code that was available already, esp. if it was already a robust solution. Anyways, I will close my own question if there are no answers within 1 day, but it's a shame this question cannot be asked here.

Comment: Albeit a little late, [here is an article (with code)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5163931/Fast-String-Matching-with-Wildcards-Globs-and-Giti) for processing `.gitignore` formated rules (globs/lines). I already made a port of the code to C#, including a few updates. My goal is/was to create a similar backup/zipping application. Did you already make your application? It is free?

Comment: @Julo whoa, nice work!! To answer your question, over the years I have come back to wishing I had this, but still there is no easy solution. I did find some solutions for overall backups, its just private, because it's not satisfactory, because programmed in very limited hours, and ultimately with no true gitignore parser (I found some C# lib that got git changed files and something or other and tapped into that, but it's been a while). Let us know if you're posting such an application / code somewhere / sometime!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to make suggestions without knowing exactly what you want to do with the list (use it in a build script, process the files in some way, just view them on a UI, etc.)

I couldn't find one in C#, but [this JavaScript gitignore parser](https://github.com/codemix/gitignore-parser) doesn't have a lot of code to convert and it exposes both an `accepts` and a `denies` method to get a list of included or ignored files. It is fairly well documented, has tests, and the regular expressions it uses would work just as well in C# as they do in JavaScript.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981583/php-filtering-files-and-paths-according-gitignore#20121494) would work from C#, provided you have Git installed on the machine where your C# code is running.

Also note that the [Git Source Control Provider](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) plugin for Visual Studio provides the list right in the IDE, along with the ability to check boxes and commit certain files together and a lot of other functionality that is difficult to do on the command line.

> NOTE: The Git Source Control Provider is open source (written in C#) and you can view the source [here](https://gitscc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), but it may be much more involved to reverse engineer than the JavaScript project.

Comment: Thanks for this answer NightOwl! All those references are very helpful, including the last one.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the best way to parse `.gitignore` files (and the other files Git uses, such as `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`) is to get Git to do it for you. :-) (In your case, most cases in fact, this does involve executing a git subprocess.)

#### `git check-ignore`

The [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) command can be used to detect which files are ignored and why. The `--non-matching` option makes it tell you about files that are not ignored as well, though since it still tells you about ignored files, too, and in a special format, you'll need to do a little bit of further work to get a simple list of non-ignored files. This Bourne shell function does the trick:

```
find_nonignored() {
    find . -path ./.git -prune -o -print \
        | git check-ignore --verbose --non-matching --stdin \
        | sed -n -e 's,\t./,\t,' -e 's,^::\t*,,p' \
}
```

#### How It Works

The `find` command finds all files in and below the current working directory, which should be somewhere in the tree you're trying to filter. We exclude the top-level `.git` subdirectory and everything under it from the output, if present; `/.git/` is not in a typical `.gitignore` file because Git ignores it automatically and thus is is normally considered "not ignored" by `git check-ignore`.

`git check-ignore` will print out `--non-matching` files only in `--verbose` mode because it's only in that mode where it prints out the extra information that would tell you if the file is ignored or not. (It always prints ignored files.) The paths come out one per line in the format

> *source*:*linenum*:*pattern*<TAB>*path*

The colon-separated fields are information about what caused the path to be ignored (such as a line in the `.gitignore` file) and will be empty if the file is not ignored.

The `sed` command then filters the output to show only the paths of the ignored files. The `-n` option tells it not to print out the input lines by default. The first substitution pattern replaces `<TAB>./` with just `<TAB>`, removing the leading `./`, for purely aesthetic reasons. The second substitution does the real work, removing any `::<TAB>` (indicating no "ignore" information) that starts a line and, if that substitution happened, printing what's left of the line which is a non-ignored path.

You can filter this further to do additional processing; I built this for a script that does markdown checking along these lines:

```
markdownlint $(find_nonignored | grep '\.md$')
```

#### Notes

1. This code includes untracked files (i.e., have never been added to the Git repo or staged) in the output, which is usually what you want. (Test systems, for example, should still check new files even before they've had `git add` run on them.) Beware that other solutions involving `git ls-files` and the like usually don't do this.
2. The above code relies on using GNU `sed`, which interprets `\t` as a tab. If you're using BSD `sed` (such as on MacOS) you probably need to tweak this slightly. Check the comments to see if someone has a hint for this.
3. All the code here breaks on paths with spaces or other "unusual" characters; it needs to be modified in several places (such as using `-print0` with `find`) to fix this. I do not address issues like this here in order to keep the explanation simple. I also leave for others the generalization of the function to work on arbitrary paths rather than just the current working directory.

Comment: How is this different from just: `git ls-files --cached --others --exclude-standard`?  It seems that invoking just that one git command would be more straight-forward and efficient.

Comment: @BobBell, you should convert your comment into an answer. That is much cleaner and works across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a C# library, you can check this out as well.

> .gitignore based parser implemented in C# according to the .gitignore spec 2.29.2. The library is tested against real git status outputs. The tests use LibGit2Sharp for that.

https://github.com/goelhardik/ignore

It's kind of a port of other open source libraries and so far looks like it works well for my other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! It’s surprisingly a very short source code, looks entirely RegEx run (https://github.com/goelhardik/ignore/blob/main/src/Ignore/ReplacerStash.cs). I may not get time to test this out for a bit, but till then if anyone can confirm this works well and you think it should be the answer, let us know.