# Repair git broken link from commit to commit

Tags: git, commit, corruption, recovery

I have a situation where a `git fsck` call returns several broken links. This is because, for this repository, a `rm` command was run and several write protected files were deleted (mistakes were made). There is also no recent backup of this repository (again, mistakes were made). Because Git was being used the repository was not a total loss, but some of the history has been scrambled. This escaped notice until recently when a re-sync to source was to be done and, because of the broken history, this failed.

I would like to repair this history (if possible) so that it can be merged with the upstream source. I recognize that I will not be able to get the full history back because some files are just gone, but I would like to keep as much of it as I can with things working correctly.

I've reviewed Linus' email, "How to recover a corrupted blob object," ([MIT hosted copy](http://web.mit.edu/git/www/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.html)) and have also looked at:

[How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Repair corrupted Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271263/repair-corrupted-git-repository)

along with many others but I'm not seeing much advise for the broken link from commit to commit errors. Note, I did make a copy of this repository so I'm not wiping anything.

The results of `git fsck` are

```
    $ git fsck
    broken link from commit <SHA1>
                  to commit <SHA2>
    broken link from   tree <SHA3>
                  to   blob <SHA4>
    ...
    dangling blob <SHA5>
    missing commit <SHA2>
    missing blob <SHA4>
    ...
```

When I go through the git history via `git log` eventually I get the error

```
error: Could not read <SHA2>
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit <SHA1>
```

which is near(ish) to where the last backup exists but not quite there so I have no overlapping coverage. I wanted to try traversing the history in reverse, thinking I could move through my log from the oldest commit to the newest but

```
$ git log --reverse
error: Could not read <SHA2>
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit <SHA1>
```

so I can't try and bound the commit on both sides (unless someone knows how to do that). I tried using `git repair` which seemed to be able to get past some of the issues but not all of them. It also seems to be corrupting things since now with `git log`

```
$ git log
...
error: Could not read <SHA6>
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit <SHA7>
```

which occurs much sooner in the history than the   issue. Interestingly, this commit DOES exist in my original un-repaired repository. Copying over the sha file gets me past the failure only for another one to crop up which also exists.

It suggested I run `git repair --force` but that ended up re-initializing the repository entirely which is not really what I wanted either.

What can I do to restore this repository to working order?

Comment: The "broken link" complaint really just means that `git fsck` was unable to retrieve the given hash ID as a valid object of the necessary type. That's why you see them as "missing" shortly after that: Git was unable to retrieve them at all. fsck might complain similarly (but slightly differently) if, for instance, a commit claimed that its parent commit was hashX and hashX exists but is not a commit object (is a tree, blob, or annotated-tag object).

Comment: I'm not really sure what `git repair` actually does, but reading the top level claims on [this page](https://git-repair.branchable.com/) suggests that it will succeed if and only if it can get the objects it destroys back from a related Git repository that it finds through the various remote Git URLs it finds in the configuration.

Comment: @torek Okay, that makes more sense for `git repair`. I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. I've made some progress such that `git log` can now fully build but `git fsck` still shows the missing commit and `git gc` also chokes.

Answer (score 5):

@LeGEC provided the final pieces for me to get this together but I think it's worthwhile to present the full approach I used. Note: I expect that a lot of the things I was able to do are specific to my case BUT there are some things that can be generalized.

When looking at the results of `git fsck` I found that there were several dangling commits. When I checked out those hashes, I found segments of good commits. So a repository which had an original structure of

```
(a)->(b)->(c)->(d)->(e)->(f)->(g)->(h)->(i)->(j)
```

after the, lets call it, "ill advised," `rm` command might be left in a state like

```
(b)->(c) (e)->(f) (h)->(i)->(j)
```

As stated in the question, the backup was very old and had the form

```
(a)->(b)
```

but that's it. What one can do is to use `git replace` to try and solve this problem. BE WARNED `git replace` seems to be an excellent tool to truly destroy your repository. I did this on a copy of my original repository and I am VERY glad it wasn't the real deal!

We will build our new repository on a new (good) foundation. We first initialize a fresh repository from the backup we do have.

```
$ mkdir my/new/fixed/repository
$ cd my/new/fixed/repository
$ git init
```

Now, from our backup (which doesn't cover the full space of the corrupted repository) we will unpack the existing structure such as it is.

```
$ git remote add origin /path/to/backup/repository
$ get remote fetch
$ get checkout --track my-broken-branch # This may not be necessary
```

To avoid messing anything up with our corrupted repository, we make a copy

```
$ cd /path/to/repository/root
$ mkdir repository-copy
$ cp -R /path/to/broken/repository /path/to/repository-copy
$ cd /path/to/repository-copy
```

First things first, lets try to use our previous repository to fix what we can:

```
git remote add backup /path/to/backup/repository
git unpack-objects < /path/to/backup/repository/.git/objects/pack/pack-*.pack
```

Okay, lets see what the damage is:

```
$ git fsck
broken link from  commit <SHA1>
              to  commit <SHA2>
broken link from    tree <SHA3>
              to    blob <SHA4>
...
dangling commit <SHA5>
...
missing commit <SHA2>
...
missing blob <SHA4>
...
dangling commit <SHA6>
...
```

Of interest are the dangling commits because those are likely to be the little sub-branches that we want to try and stitch back together. Note, these commits are NOT always in chronological order. For me the order happened to be (from oldest to newest) `<SHA5>-<SHA6>` but you will likely have your own knot to untangle. You can check the commit date/time by running

```
$ git show -s <SHAX>
```

One thing to note at this point is this, if you are in the broken repository copy, and then run the command `git log` you will be able to traverse the repository until you run into  at which time you will get the error:

```
error: Could not read <SHA2>
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit <SHA1>
```

So we need to replace the parent of  with a commit that is actually good. The pattern for this is called a graft but doing a pure graft is no-longer considered best practice ([How do git grafts and replace differ? (Are grafts now deprecated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800692/how-do-git-grafts-and-replace-differ-are-grafts-now-deprecated)) because of the new(er) best practice `git replace`.

So I now make  the parent of

```
$ git replace --graft <SHA1> <SHA6>
$ git fsck
broken link from  commit <SHA1>
              to  commit <SHA2>
broken link from    tree <SHA3>
              to    blob <SHA4>
...
broken link from  commit <SHA7>
              to  commit <SHA8>
```

So a new broken commit has appeared. If I investigate that commit using `git log` I find that the previous commit ended prior to the remaining dangling commit's commit time. So I'm going to graft those two together. Note, this may not be a safe thing to do if you have lots of people working on this repository but, in this case, I believe it to be okay.

```
$ git replace --graft <SHA7> <SHA5>
$ git fsck
broken link from  commit <SHA1>
              to  commit <SHA2>
broken link from    tree <SHA3>
              to    blob <SHA4>
...
broken link from  commit <SHA7>
              to  commit <SHA8>
```

No new dangling commits and, in my case,  was able to connect to my backup repository. In other cases I imagine this will not always be true. If so, you can eventually get to the point where you could graft the head of the remote repository as the remaining bad commit link.

Now we must deal with the missing blobs. You can try and repair them following Linus' method or, if you are willing to accept the missing history, you can use git replace again to excise them from the history. The general approach is

```
$ git ls-tree <SHA3>
...
100644 blob <SHA4>  my-magic-file
...
$ git log --raw --all --full-history -- subdirectory/my-magic-file | grep -B 20 -A 20 "<SHA4>" # May just need to use first few values from SHA4
# commit information after missing blob
# commit information for missing blob
# commit information before missing blob
$ git replace --graft <commit-after-missing-blob> <commit-before-missing-blob>
```

Repeat this until `git rev-list --objects my/branch` runs to completion.

Now, you need to remove the extraneous commits. Fortunately, a new tool has been developed to do just this: `git-filter-repo`. This tool will commit our grafts and refactor the history.

```
$ git filter-repo --force
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100%...
Checking objects: 100%...
```

Now lets see if we can successfully fetch our repository from our broken branch.

```
$ cd /path/to/my/new/fixed/repository
$ git fetch broken my/branch
...
From /path/to/my/broken/repository
 * branch            my/branch        -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      my/branch        -> broken/my/branch
```

And, because we have a common history with the remote we can now merge with our previously broken branches

```
$ git merge broken/my/branch
```

And the history is once again clean.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Frustrated with [my similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680946/how-to-clean-damaged-objects-in-git-repository) I followed your advice. It seems they changed the behavior of `git replace --graft` As i don't get any changes after it in `git fsck` as this doesn't use those replacements. Nevertheless I made my other commands run (log, blame, etc.) which use the replacements.

Answer (score 2):

(from your comments : I'll assume you managed to build a branch with a history of commits, which you deem satisfying)

You can create a fresh clone next to your broken one, and iteratively pull what you can from `broken` on top of `fresh`, to both check that you are pulling in valid objects, and to work on a valid repo.

Start with a fresh clone :

```
# next to your broken 'myproject' directory :
git clone <url> fresh
cd fresh
git remote add broken ../myproject
```

See if you can fecth the branch you created in your original `myproject` directory :

```
# from fresh :
git fetch broken my/branch
```

If this action works, this means you pulled in only valid commits, pointing at valid trees and valid blobs, and you are in a stable state.

If on the other hand this action doesn't work : you will need to find out what commits have a valid content.

For trees : run `git ls-tree -r <commit>` on all commits from "the last one that's in the remote" to the head of your branch. If a tree is invalid, `git ls-tree -r` will mention an error.

For blobs : run `git cat-file -p` on all blobs mentioned by the `git ls-tree -r` commands above. Again : you will have an error if a blob is missing.

Comment: This didn't end up working for me since, even after a `git replace --graft` I'm still seeing the old broken link with `git fsck`. I'm not sure why it hasn't been cleaned up

Comment: `git fsck` scans all objects, so it is expected that it still inspects those broken objects. I found back the correct command to check an existing commit (instead of "all the objects in my repo") : `git rev-list --objects my/branch`

Comment: `git replace` alone does not rewrite objects, it merely "hides" them from some commands like `git log`. To actually rewrite the commits so that they match this new history, you can use [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) : after running your `git replace --graft` command, run `git filter-repo --force` (see [this example](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_parent_rewriting_2))

Comment: I guess to be more clear, I issued `git replace --graft <SHA1> <good_SHA>` but I'm still getting the `broken link from commit <SHA1> to commit <SHA2>` error in `git fsck`. `git rev-list --objects my/branch` seems to be clean (no errors anyway). <SHA1> doesn't show up in the `git rev-list` call.

Comment: Okay, `git-filter-repo` was the silver bullet I needed. After running that and cleaning up the blobs I've gotten the repository in working order. If you want to update your answer to include `git-filter-repo` I'll accept it as the answer. I will also upload my own answer that goes into gory detail.