# migrating a git repository via rsync

Tags: git

A while ago we setup a git repository for internal use on a local server. The server is not on a business line and thus has a non-static ip.

We want to move the git origin from the local server to a new remote server (this is our private dedicated server, not github or similar).

Can we just rsync the entire git directory over to the new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git repositories have nothing linking them to their directory or server (unless you configured something specifically).  You can move them like any other directory of files.  A USB stick, scp, rsync, mv, zip, tar... whatever.

Comment: Yea i just rsync'd the whole thing over then did a clone of the new repo from the remote server to my local machine.. working perfectly. Couldn't believe it could be that simple.. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Though the simplest way would surely be to do a `git clone`, yes, you can use rsync.

Comment: If it's a bare repository you're moving (ie. what people push to and pull from with no checkout) with clone you'll want `git clone --bare` and probably `--mirror`.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way (which would *not* bring with it local config or hooks, which can be specific to the local environment, and have sensitive information you wouldn't always want to include in an archive) would be to use git bundle.

```
git bundle create /tmp/myrepo.bundle --all
```

See "[How can I email someone a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309)"

That creates only *one* file (easy to copy around), which you can clone or fetch from:
On the target server

```
git clone myrepo.bundle
cd myrepo
```

Comment: @John that is the recommended best practice, well over the rsync.