# Create a Git bundle and share it remotely

Tags: javascript, git, command-line

I've created a bundle file of a private project of mine, and I would like to share it with someone. They ask me to provide the git bundle file generated.

Can I just email them the single bundle file? ...or do I need to attach the folder of the project itself as well?

Comment: A bundle is a self contained file. Just send them the one file. `git bundle create ../reponame.bundle --all --tags`.

Comment: Considering the title of that old question I answered in 2010, you can email the file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309

Comment: I used this command --> git bundle create project.bundle master.  What is the difference from the one above?

Comment: The recipient can use `git clone` (assuming the bundle was made with --all) to recreate the full repo, though it's origin will be set to the bundle!

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just email them the single bundle file?

Yep, that the point behind the bundle.
Its a full **read-only** repository.

Once you have the bundle you can share it.

---

> git bundle will only package references that are shown by git show-ref: this includes heads, tags, and remote heads.

---

#### `git bundle create ../reponame.bundle --all`

`--all`- **get all refs**

This command creates bundle with all the source code and all other info like tags.

Even due that `--all` is not documented its much better to use it.

**Note** : `--all` would not include `remote-tracking` branches !!!