# Git and GUI with mounted repo

Tags: git, webserver, repository, git-gui

I'm using git gui - git kraken. My problem is to use it with the folder, that placed on webserver. I use sshsf to mount the folder with my website to local folder and point git kraken to that folder as my local repo. But it working too slow. Is there any other methods to solve that problem?

Comment: Do you want the repository (the `.git` subdirectory) located on server also or only the working copy?

Answer (score 0):

Git is best used on a local repo. Anything network-related introduces too much latency, hence the slow GUI you see.

It is best to clone (or [export as a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309)) your repo from your webserver to a local folder, and make your GUI working with said local folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in conflicts, that happened, when first you pushed from local repo to remote and later someone pushed his changes from webserver repo with yours untracked for git files. Because local repo and webserver repo don't know anything about each other. The solution was to create branch and speicify a directory for it on webserver. Then clone it to local machine and work with it through ssh, but provide any git operations only with local repo and use webserver directory just to debug your changes.