# is `git bundle` suitable for making back-up copies?

Tags: git, git-bundle

I want a simple way to back up my git repos, so I'm considering `git bundle`.

I am presently unable to confirm that I can recover the full content of a bundled branch(es) relying on a `*.bundle` file. I'm confused, because I notice talk about "deltas" being saved, maybe not other content.

Can someone please confirm that `git bundle` is a suitable approach for backing up projects, that is, no work will be lost.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git bundle create /tmp/foo-all --all
```

This results in a single file.
See [ProGit: little bundle of joy](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html).
See also "[How can I email someone a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784)"

Note that this does not backup hook scripts and that this is by design since the hook scripts might contain sensitive information.

---

For using that bundle, you can clone it:

```
git clone /tmp/foo-all newFolderOutsideAnyGitRepo
```

Comment: FYI - with git version 2.3.5, I see no effect for the `--all`. option, whereas one might think it includes 'all' branches, it does not.