# Export github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a project I am working on that is currently on in a repository on my GitHub.
I am doing as a part of my degree, I will be shortly handing it over to the client

I was wondering if there is a way to export the entire repository including all the branches and related history so that it can be stored prior to handing on to future developer?

Comment: You can fork the repo before transferring ownership to the client/successor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**(1)** Use **git archive** (for backup one branch) like the below command (Suppose you are inside Git local repository):

```
git archive master --format=zip --output=java_exmamples.zip
```

you will see file `java_exmamples.zip` (in the same folder) is the backup of master branch.

**(2)** Use **git bundle** (for backup all branches)

A real example:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/donhuvy/java_examples.git
cd java_examples.git/
git bundle create repo.bundle --all
```

`repo.bundle` is the file what you need (full back up) in the same directory.

How to restore from file `repo.bundle`:

```
git clone repo.bundle
```

**Reference**

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/tips-and-tricks#bundle-the-repository

Comment: Not git archive: it does not export the full history. And git bundle is what I already suggested.

Comment: Thank-you very much, looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Beside forking it (which is a clone on the remote side: GitHub), you can also [export it as a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309).

From your own local clone, you can type (using [`git bundle`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-bundle.html))

```
git bundle create /tmp/myrepo.bundle --all
```

That will give you *one* file (easy to copy around), from which you can clone back your repo at any time.

```
cd /a/new/path
git clone /tmp/myrepo.bundle myrepo
cd myrepo
pwd
  /a/new/path/myrepo
```