# files missing in the downloaded file that is exported by github

Tags: github

I followed these 2 instructions and downloaded the compressed file.

1. Visit your account settings page.
2. Click "Start export" in the "Export account data" section.

I can see the folders like this.

```
branches
hooks
info
logs
objects
refs
config
description
HEAD
packed-refs
```

But I do not see the files in any of the folders. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[Requesting an archive of your personal account’s data](https://docs.github.com/en/github/understanding-how-github-uses-and-protects-your-data/requesting-an-archive-of-your-personal-accounts-data)" is clear.
This is about *metadata*, not data.

> GitHub stores repository and profile *metadata* from your personal account's activity.
> You can export your personal account's data through settings on GitHub.com or with the User Migration API.

You can see [another export example here](https://gist.github.com/maboloshi/caa220797731849f4c5df05cd72d9091): metadata only, no files.

This [dates from 2018](https://github.blog/2018-12-19-download-your-data/):

> The archive will contain your profile data, plan, and any email addresses connected with your account in addition to the issues, pull requests, comments, reviews, releases, projects, events, attachments, milestones, and settings for each of your repositories—along with basic information about the users who have interacted with them.

Other services, like [GitLab, have their own process](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html) to import GitHub repositories.

Or you can [clone them all in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66547645/6309), make [a bundle for each one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39940458/6309), and store those files (one per repository) wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your process.

**First:** Check if your zip app works correctly and can extract it. Here is a [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/i-cant-extract-zipped-files-all-i-get-is-empty/4784eb7f-8adb-4654-81e3-c7f408f1ce52) that sometimes zip can't extract files and shows empty folders.

**Second:** Maybe a problem with GitHub. Try it again hope it will help.
I have some problems with Github too, and I don't know what happened to Github nowadays.

**Edit**
Make sure that the size shows in GitHub match the size of the downloaded folders.
[image]