# Why GIT reports "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree" when exporting from bare repo?

Tags: git, export, archive

if I export from bare GIT repository using git archive command I get error message:
"fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree", altough the export passes properly.

So my question is: Is there any issue when exporting from bare repository? I checked the exported archive and it looks alright.

Comment: You aren't by any chance still using 1.6.0.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't actually get that warning - I'm fairly certain it was a bug which was resolved sometime after the version you're using. I can't tell exactly when, because I haven't even managed to reproduce it at all (I tried v1.5.3.4, v1.6.2, and a build from current master.)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I get the message with git version 1.5.6.5 (Debian stable).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in ["backing up project which uses git"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046918/backing-up-project-which-uses-git/2047141#2047141), [`git bundle`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) would be more appropriate.

> [`git archive`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) just creates tarballs of trees (snapshots) but doesn't preserve commits and history.

But you may be after a simple copy, and not the all history bundled in one file.

That being said, if `git archive` expect a working tree (as illustrated in "[How to do a Git export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)"), its error message is expecting in a bare repo which, by definition, has no working directory.

Comment: I need to create an archive consisting of pure working copy, so git bundle is probably not usable. 

I can of course clone to normal (not bare) repository and call git archive in there, but I don't know if it's necessary, because git archive apparently works in bare repositories as well. 

I just don't know if the error message really means that the export could fail or if the message is there due to some historical reasons.