# Git Clone: Just the files, please?

Tags: git

I want to clone a GIT repo and NOT end up with a `.git` directory. In other words I just want the files. Is there a way to do this?

`git clone --no-checkout` did the exact opposite of what I want (gave me just the `.git` directory).

I am trying to do that for a *remote* repo, not a local one, meaning this is **not a duplicate** of "[How to do a “git export” (like “svn export”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)" (even though the solution might end up being the same).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a "git export" (like "svn export")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I'm trying to do this from a remote repo. Not sure if that makes this question unique, though.

Comment: Though this is a newer question, but I think this is worth to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497457/git-clone-without-git-directory

Comment: See my [update answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946745/6309): `git archive` is now (Q4 2017) more precise and won't include empty folders.

Comment: You are welcome. Apparently, your comment was flagged and removed... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/134259?m=39402889#39402889

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The git command that would be the closest from what you are looking for would by **[`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)**.
See [backing up project which uses git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046918/backing-up-project-which-uses-git/2047141#2047141): it will include in an archive all files (including submodules if you are using the [`git-archive-all`](http://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh/blob/master/git-archive-all.sh) script)

You can then use that archive anywhere, giving you back only files, no `.git` directory.

```
git archive --remote=<repository URL> | tar -t
```

If you need folders and files just from the first level:

```
git archive --remote=<repository URL> | tar -t --exclude="*/*"
```

To list only first-level folders of a remote repo:

```
git archive --remote=<repository URL> | tar -t --exclude="*/*" | grep "/"
```

Note: that [does not work for GitHub (not supported)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079188/6309)

So you would need [to clone (shallow to quicken the clone step), and then  archive locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839052/6309):

```
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git
cd yyy
git archive --format=tar aTag -o aTag.tar
```

---

Another option would be to do a shallow clone (as mentioned below), but locating the .git folder elsewhere.

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/another/folder.git clone --depth=1 /url/to/repo
```

The repo folder would include only the file, without `.git`.

Note: `git --git-dir`  is an option of the [command `git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git), not [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

---

Update with Git 2.14.X/2.15 (Q4 2017): it will **make sure to avoid adding empty folders**.

> "`git archive`", especially when used with pathspec, stored an empty
>   directory in its output, even though Git itself never does so.
>   This has been fixed.

See [commit 4318094](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43180940473cdafa95eb6b63b0efa9e36ac905da) (12 Sep 2017) by [René Scharfe (``)](https://github.com/).
Suggested-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 62b1cb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62b1cb7b135d07912a9e0025b54be39dfc79e1dd), 25 Sep 2017)</sup>

> ### `archive`: don't add empty directories to archives
>
> While git doesn't track empty directories, `git archive` can be tricked into putting some into archives.
>   While that is supported by the object database, it can't be represented in the index and thus it's unlikely to occur in the wild.
>
> As empty directories are not supported by git, they should also not be
>   written into archives.
>   If an empty directory is really needed then it can be tracked and archived by placing an empty `.gitignore` file in it.

Comment: This worked for me. I would add one more thing. If you don't care about the .git folder at all, then I would use this command: `git --git-dir=/dev/null clone --depth=1 /url/to/repo`

Comment: This does not remove the .git folder

Comment: @VonC I tried:
    git --git-dir=/dev/null clone --depth=1 /url/to/repo

Comment: @aliasav what version of git did you used? And what version of git is used on the remote server side?

Comment: `git --git-dir=/dev/null clone --depth=1 /url/to/repo` not working. I'm using git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63). check details with running  `GIT_TRACE_SETUP=true`

Comment: @Bhavik then I guess my answer stands: specify a path which is outside local path of the repo your are cloning.

Comment: yeah. /dev/null was the first thing that occured to me while reading this (hence one of the upvotes), but unfortunately it doesn't work `git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)`

Comment: @andrew " In git version 2.11 there is no `--git-dir` option for `clone` command. There is `--separate-git-dir`.": no `--git-dir` is an option of  `git`, not `git clone`

Comment: Running `git archive --remote=https://github.com/pornel/dssim.git @ | tar -t` I get `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`. Doesn't it work with GitHub? Also, what does the `@` mean?

Comment: @AndréWerlang 7 years later... I am not too sure of the `@`: I have removed it. Also GitHub does not support a remote `git archive`: I have edited the answer to propose an alternative.

Answer (score 67):

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=<repository URL> HEAD | tar xf -
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision)

Comment: `--format=tar` is unnecessary. "tar" is the default output, no need to specify.

Comment: piping into `tar x` is sufficient

Comment: on github this results in 'fatal: operation not supported by protocol'

Answer (score 50):

You can create a shallow clone to only get the last few revisions:

```
 git clone --depth 1 git://url
```

then either simply delete the .git directory or use `git archive` to export your tree.

Comment: Howt o prevent this error when I update it by repeating the clone:

"   fatal: destination path 'XYZ' already exists and is not an empty directory."

Comment: @SohailSi: either clone to a new location or remove the old directory. You're probably better off just fetching the new revisions, if you want to update your local copy.

Comment: @Sohail First time you get files using `clone` then every time you need to update always use `pull`.

Answer (score 7):

Why not perform a clone and then delete the `.git` directory so that you just have a bare working copy?

Edit: Or in fact why use clone at all? It's a bit confusing when you say that you want a git repo but without a `.git` directory. If you mean that you just want a copy of some state of the tree then why not do `cp -R` in the shell instead of the git clone and then delete the `.git` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for that. The files are in a git repo. I was hoping to be able to direct Mac users to get a copy of the repo in one line, without it becoming a GIT repo.

Comment: You shouldn't have people directly getting code from the repo if they can't use it (ie don't have the Git repository).

Comment: @Amoss Releasing a tarball so that people aren't constantly grabbing the latest code?

Comment: @mathepic: and to release a tarball you need a way of getting a clean working copy out of the repository - which is exactly the question that was posed.

Comment: @Amoss it sounds like he wants to have the user download it with git then delete the .git repository. In any case, this is the wrong thing to do anyway. For example, I wouldn't check ./configure in to the source control because its autogenerated with configure.ac, but you want to distribute it with ./configure.

Comment: The .git folder is HUGE. I don't need to be spending all that extra disk usage copying .git. I just need the files. I'm sure there's a way to do this....

Comment: Reading the answer below and then doing a bit of googling led to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export If you take a look at the use of git archive --remote then it does exactly what you (and the original poster) are looking for. Edit: which is what Jon answered lower down.

Answer (score 6):

## git checkout -f

There's another way to do this by splitting the repo from the working tree.

This method is useful if you need to update these git-less git files on a regular basis. For instance, I use it when I need to check out source files and build an artifact, then copy the artifact into a different repo just for deployment to a server, and I also use it when pushing source code to a server when I want the source code to checkout and build into the www directory.

We'll make two folders, one for the git one for the working files:

```
mkdir workingfiles
mkdir barerepo.git
```

initialize a bare git repo:

```
cd barerepo.git
git --bare init
```

Then create a post-receive hook:

```
touch hooks/post-receive
chmod ug+x hooks/post-receive
```

Edit post-receive in your favorite editor:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/workingfiles git checkout -f
# optional stuff:
cd down/to/some/directory
[do some stuff]
```

Add this as a remote:

```
git remote add myserver ssh://user@host:/path/to/barerepo.git
```

Now every time you push to this bare repo it will checkout the working tree to `/workingfiles/`. But `/workingfiles/` itself is not under version control; running `git status` in `/workingfiles/` will give the error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /data)`. It's just plain files.

Unlike other solutions `rm -r .git` command is not needed, so if `/workingfiles/` is some other git repo you don't have to worry about the command used removing the other repo's git files.

Comment: Agreed. A post-receive hook on a bare repo is possible here. +1

Comment: a lot of work if you're just trying to get the files

Comment: It's not a lot of work if you want just the files on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use git at all, just append "/zipball/master/" to URL ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048489)).

### Downloading

This solution is the closest to "Download ZIP" button on github page. One advantage is lack of .git directory. The other one - it downloads single ZIP file instead of each file one by one, and this can make huge difference. It can be done from command line by wget: `wget -O "$(basename $REPO_URL)".zip "$REPO_URL"/zipball/master/`. The only problem is, that some repositories might not have master branch at all. If this is the case, "master" in URL should be replaced by appropriate branch.

### Unzipping

Once the ZIP is there, the final unzipped directory name may still be pretty weird and unexpected. To fix this, name can be extracted by [this script](https://superuser.com/questions/505396/find-out-the-name-of-a-folder-in-a-root-directory-inside-zip-file/505444#505444), and `mv`-ed to  `basename` of the URL. Final `script.sh` could look something like (evals for dealing with spaces):

```
#Script for downloading from github. If no BRANCH_NAME is given, default is "master".
#usage: script.sh URL [BRANCH_NAME]
__repo_name__='basename "$1"'
__repo_name__="$(eval $__repo_name__)"
__branch__="${2:-master}"
#downloading
if [ ! -e ./"$__repo_name__"".zip" ] ; then
wget -O "$__repo_name__"".zip" "$1""/zipball/$__branch__/"
fi
#unpacking and renaming
if [ ! -e ./"$__repo_name__" ] ; then
unzip "$__repo_name__"".zip" && 
__dir_name__="$(unzip -qql $__repo_name__.zip | sed -r '1 {s/([ ]+[^ ]+){3}\s+//;q}')" &&
rm "$__repo_name__"".zip" &&
mv "$__dir_name__" "$__repo_name__"
fi
```

### Maintaining

This approach shoud do the work for "just the files", and it is great for quick single-use access to small repositories.

However. If the source is rather big, and the only possibility to update is to download and rebuild all, then (to the best of my knowledge) there is no possibility to update `.git`-less directory, so the full repo has to be downloaded again. Then the best solution is - as VonC has already explained - to stick with shallow copy `git clone --depth 1 $REPO_URL`. But what next? To "check for updates" see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git), and to update see great wiki-like [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41081908).

Comment: Great answer! About the `Maintaining` section, full repo has not to be downloaded again. How about first time you download using `clone --depth 1` then every time you need to update always use `pull`, right?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
git --work-tree=/tmp/files_without_dot_git clone --depth=1 \
  https://git.yourgit.your.com/myawesomerepo.git \
  /tmp/deleteme_contents_of_dot_git
```

Both the directories in /tmp are created on the fly. No need to pre-create these.

Comment: Could you describe how the command works?

Comment: It will clone the contents of the repo to the folder `/tmp/files_without_dot_git` except the `.git`  folder and the .git folder content will go to the folder `/tmp/deleteme_contents_of_dot_git` which you can delete later. So you can do `git init` in `/tmp/files_without_dot_git` folder to create a brand new repo.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you just want a copy of the source code.  If so why not just copy the directory and exclude the .git directory from the copy?

Comment: That's what I'm asking: how to do that with git... I can already tell that there's no built-in way to do it from the answers that I'm getting, though. Thanks anyway!