# Git clone without .git directory

Tags: git, version-control, git-clone

Is there a flag to pass to `git` when doing a clone, say don't clone the `.git` directory? If not, how about a flag to delete the `.git` directory after the clone?

Comment: This question is _not_ a dupe of [How to do a "git export" (like "svn export")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export).

This question asks on how to _clone_ a (remote) repository _without_ the `.git` directory.

The alleged dupe asks how to _export_ an existing repository where you already have the `.git` directory.

Comment: Agree. You cannot `git archive` remote repository as the "possible duplicate" solution says.

Answer (score 298):

Use

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=master git://someserver/somerepo dirformynewrepo
rm -rf ./dirformynewrepo/.git
```

- The depth option will make sure to copy the least bit of history possible to get that repo.
- The branch option is optional and if not specified would get the default branch.
- The second line will make your directory `dirformynewrepo` not a Git repository any more.
- If you're doing recursive submodule clone, the depth and branch parameter don't apply to the submodules.

Comment: For those interested, it's one of the [word designators](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html), part of the [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) feature in Bash and zsh.

Comment: Is there a way to get the depth=1 of all branches in the repo? not just master or specified branch

Comment: you do that with the --no-single-branch option, since --depth implies --single-branch, you can un-imply it with --no-single-branch.  (Taken from the git clone man page)

Comment: Great answer, this is useful when cloning from e.g. gitlab and wanting to start afresh

Comment: Using `!$`, while technically correct in this instance, does nothing to help people who don't recognise the syntax understand the answer to the actual question. It also relies on the second command directly following the first, and within the same shell. If anyone omits those implicit requirements, they may end up deleting something else entirely. Therefore I suggest your answer could be improved by explicitly specifying the name `dirformynewrepo` as an argument to the `rm` command as it will make the connection between both commands much clearer.

Comment: why wouldn't you use `git --git-dir=/dev/null` instead

Comment: @Rainb Try it. It doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Is ./dirformynewrepo the name of the repo that's being pulled or a specific folder in it

Comment: @Wayne `dirformynewrepo` is the local dir where you want to copy the repo to. The name of the live repo in this example is `somerepo`

Answer (score 36):

since you only want the files, you don't need to treat it as a git repo.

```
rsync -rlp --exclude '.git' user@host:path/to/git/repo/ .
```

and this only works with local path and remote ssh/rsync path, it may not work if the remote server only provides git:// or https:// access.

Comment: that will not take .gitignore into consideration?

Comment: itub is right, this is just copying the work tree. git checkout used to do that properly, now it does not any longer.

Comment: so, what do you do if the server only provides git:// access?

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively, if you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) installed, you can use the following command:

`npx degit GIT_REPO`

`npx` comes with Node, and it allows you to run binary node-based packages without installing them first (alternatively, you can first install `degit` globally using `npm i -g degit`).

[Degit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/degit) is a tool created by Rich Harris, the creator of Svelte and Rollup, which he uses to quickly create a new project by cloning a repository without keeping the git folder. But it can also be used to clone any repo once...

Answer (score 11):

```
git clone --separate-git-dir=$(mktemp -u) --depth=1 <repo> <dir> && rm <dir>/.git
```

I like this solution more because I don't like `rm -rf`ing things automatically. It just `rm`s a .git file, which means it could never accidentally `rm -rf` a wrong .git directory

It has a dependency on `mktemp` command so it'll work *nix systems (from what I see this needs further work for the `mktemp` to work on MacOS, so if anyone wants to comment a working solution I'll add it)

In zsh, I made that a function so I ensure a `dir` value is defined:

```
alias np='node-project'
function node-project() {
  dir=${1:-.}
  git clone --separate-git-dir=$(mktemp -u) --depth=1 <my-node-repo> $dir && rm $dir/.git
}
```

### Explanation

The `--separate-git-dir` flag lets you specify a path for the .git directory. The resulting "project" will have a .git file (not a directory) whose content will be a single line:

```
gitdir: <the dir you specified in the flag>
```

Because we used a tmp dir with the `mktemp` command, the actual `.git` directory contents will end up in a tmp dir. We also use a `--depth=1` so it takes less space on tmp dirs.

Comment: Point of clarification - this still creates a `.git` equivalent folder, it's just stored in wherever `mktemp` chooses to put it instead of the `git clone` destination. When you `rm <dir>/.git` as per this answer, you're effectively just removing a symlink to the tmp folder created elsewhere with the normal `.git` files.  The files are being left until the OS processes automatically cleans up the temporary directory used by `--separate-git-dir`. So, to properly clean up, you may still want the `rm -rf`, just for the `git` folder stored in the temp folder instead of in the clone target.

Answer (score 5):

For those who doubt [the `--depth 1` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11498124/9157799) because it still download the `.git` directory and you need to manually remove it afterward, maybe you need to know [how git clone actually works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889009/9157799).

When you normally clone a repo, git download all your files (spanning across commits) into the `.git` directory. When you clone with `--depth 1`, git only downloads the latest version of the files into `.git`. After that, git will [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or retrieve those files from `.git` into the working directory (no more download).

And oftentimes, because the file objects inside `.git` is compressed, you will save more bandwidth by downloading the files with `git clone --depth 1` rather than downloading the uncompressed files. And for some people with slow internet, that is worth the price (the need to run `rm -rf`).

I personally think [the `git archive` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946745/9157799) is better but since it's not supported by GitHub, `--depth 1` is the way to go.

Comment: If it's GitHub, why not just `curl -L https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}/tarball/master | tar xz` ?

Comment: @DesNerger Because we can easily clone from private repo with ssh

Answer (score 2):

If the repository is on GitHub, you can simply download a ZIP file of any tag:

```
curl -L https://github.com/<user>/<repo-name>/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.3.zip | tar xz
```

This will download and uncompress the repository. The contents will be in `<repo-name>-1.2.3`, with no `.git` folder.

Comment: Very neat trick, but there are a lot of Git repositories that are not hosted on GitHub.

Comment: Good point. Well. They should simply move to github. I am joking. Well, I am sure it is possible to di similar thing also onnother hosts.

Answer (score 1):

`git archive --remote` already implements this.

Comment: Any combination of `git archive --remote` I tried from posts online failed me with `Invalid command: 'git-upload-archive '<repo>'`

Comment: Try: 

`git archive --remote git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab.git -o gitlab_15.9.3ee.tgz v15.9.3-ee`

Comment: LFS files may not be part of the archive.

Comment: Same problem here, just like @GuidoTarsia said. mr.wolle's suggestion does not help either.

Comment: It seems to be a GitHub limitation. They provide their own way to generate "download zip" URLs from the web UI. Why they do not simply support standard Git features, too, eludes me, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=master git://someserver/somerepo dirformynewrepo1
rd /s /q  .\dirformynewrepo1\.git
```

this works for windows systems

Answer (score -2):

You can always do

```
git clone git://repo.org/fossproject.git && rm -rf fossproject/.git
```

Comment: download everything and delete the dir later? for instance emacs has 95% of 1GB in the .git. so --depth=1 is the solution here clearly.

Comment: i still see the .git folder when i do depth=1

Comment: @AryehArmon of course you see it. Using --depth does not prevent the creation of .git, it just makes it a shallow copy, so much smaller size for .git. But if you do not want it there at all, you need to remove it afterwards.