# Why does git clone sometimes create a .git directory, and sometimes not?

Tags: git, git-clone

There are at least 3 previous questions explaining how to clone a repository without the .git directory:

- [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)
- [Git clone without .git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497457/git-clone-without-git-directory)
- [What's the best practice to "git clone" into an existing folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377960/whats-the-best-practice-to-git-clone-into-an-existing-folder)

From those questions, it seems you can't just run `git clone` and have the repository cloned without the `.git` directory.

Yet, in the majority of repos I've cloned, such as the one in the command below, no `.git` directory is made.

```
git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box.git
```

What determines whether a straight forward `git clone` command creates a `.git` directory or not?

Comment: Well after I cloned the repo given by you, I have a `.git` directory. So the only situation I can imagine where you don't have a .git directory is a bare repository. But even if you clone this bare repo git will create a .git folder. It is mandatory for git to work properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: Never seen a git repository without the `.git` directory. Not possible. Probably just hidden in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **always** a `.git` directory after a `git clone`. No exception. If you don't see it then it is hidden (How this happens depends on your operating system. `ls` on linux does not show files/dirs that start with a dot. You would have to use `ls -a`.)

The `.git` directory is essential as it contains all files and info used by git.

Here is what happens after the `git-clone` you mentioned:

```
/tmp % git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box.git
Cloning into 'scotch-box'...
remote: Counting objects: 83, done.
remote: Total 83 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 83
Unpacking objects: 100% (83/83), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
/tmp % cd scotch-box 
/tmp/scotch-box (git)-[master] % la
total 40K
drwxr-xr-x 4 t t 4.0K 12. Aug 14:10 .
drwxrwxrwt 8 root  root   12K 12. Aug 14:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 t t 4.0K 12. Aug 14:10 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 t t   18 12. Aug 14:10 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 t t 7.4K 12. Aug 14:10 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 t t  480 12. Aug 14:10 Vagrantfile
drwxr-xr-x 2 t t 4.0K 12. Aug 14:10 public
```

Comment: You say 'no exception' but I've just seen `git clone` on WSL clone a repo successfully, but then the .git directory is missing. I've been using *nix and git for decades and never seen anything like it, and it's not some stupid mistake on my part (like not cd-ing into the directory).

Comment: The `.git` directory is essential for git to work. If you are using "default" git and don't `git clone --bare`, you will get a `.git` directory. If you don't have this directory and git works, you are not looking in the right place. If you clone, don't have this directory and git doesn't work, you have discovered [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76296193/3683639).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are looking for `.git` in the right location? When you do a clone like `git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box.git`, the repo is actually clone in a directory `scotch-box` and hence `.git` will be at `scotch-box/.git`

On the other hand, doing:

git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box.git .

note the `.` at the end - will clone in current folder (if that is not already a git repo)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I'm not sure if it was a corrupt install or a bug in the version of git I was using (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.6).  My environment was Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL), Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.  I was cloning libjpeg-turbo and not getting a .git folder!  The issue was repeatable.

I simply updated my version of git (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.9) and the problem was gone.