# How to keep a clean history when cloning repo with submodules?

Tags: git

I have a repo A which is a template project which contains a submodule. I want to be able to clone this repository and start a new project using this template project.

This command works, but it gives me a repository initialized with the latest commit of the repo A.

```
git clone --recursive <url>
```

I would prefer to clone the repo and then commit with a custom relevant message like "init from template project" as the first commit, and not the lastest submodule commit message.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497457/git-clone-without-git-directory/11498124) says I should do (I added --recursive to clone submodules):

```
git clone --recursive --depth=1 --branch=master git://someserver/somerepo dirformynewrepo
rm -rf !$/.git
```

After that I tried:

```
git init
git submodule init
git commit -m "init from template"
git push
```

Every submodules files are not recognized as beeing a submodule, and commited as normal files. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

A

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch
git commit -m 'init from template project'
```

starts a new branch without the history.  When you still want the history, just create a commit with

```
git commit --allow-empty  -m 'init from template project'
```

You can also rewrite the top with

```
git commit --amend -m 'init from template project'
```