# Move .git one level up while keeping the source files where they are

Tags: git

There are similar questions but not quite what I need.

I have this structure in several projects:

```
/var/www/proj-a/
  app/
    .git/
    script-a.js
    script-.js
    ... more files and directories
  data/
    ... data and config files go here
```

I want to have the `.git` folder directly in the project folder, not as a sub-directory of `app`. But the repo will still only manage files in the `app` directory. In other words, I will use `.gitignore` to exclude everything inside the project directory except for the `app` directory.

The new structure should look like this:

```
/var/www/proj-a/
  .git/
  app/
    script-a.js
    script-.js
    ... more files and directories
  data/
    ... data and config files go here
  .gitignore
```

Now, in git are paths saved as absolute paths allowing me to just move the `.git` directory to the project directory without any issues; or are paths relative resulting in source files not being found? If the paths are relative, how can I achieve this change without loosing my git branches and history?

Comment: Why do you care where `.git` is? That said, you can put `.git` anywhere you like; see the `--git-dir` and `--work-path` options in `man git`.

Comment: @chepner it is more convenient to have `app` only contain source files. One example is when I want to deploy. I use `rsync` and if I did not have `.git` in `app` I could simply `rsync` the `app` directory and be done with it. Now I am `rsync`ing subdirectories of `app` one at a time.

Comment: `rsync --exclude .git/`? (Not that I condone deploying anything by simply dumping a Git checkout somewhere else; write a proper installation script.)

Comment: @MajidFouladpour In that particular situation, you can use the `--exclude` flag on `rsync`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11497654/1440565.

Comment: "in git are paths saved as absolute paths...or are paths relative...?" Git tracks paths relative to the project root, which is the folder where `.git` is located by default.

Comment: deployment is but one issue. There are other reasons I prefer the new structure. Sounds like it is not a simple mater of moving the `.git` one level up though ... Is there no way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are other reasons I prefer the new structure.
> Sounds like it is not a simple mater of moving the .git one level up though ... Is there no way?

You don't exactly move the `.git/` folder one level up.

What you can do is move the elements in the current Git repository one level *down*, under a new `app/` folder, using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

- [install `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) (python-based)
- rename `/` as `/app`: `git filter-repo --path-rename /:/app` ([Filtering based on paths](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_filtering_based_on_paths_see_also_filename_callback))

Once you have a Git repository with the right structure, you can add  the `data/` folder in it, and clone the end result as `proj-a`.

---

As noted by [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70778051/move-git-one-level-up-while-keeping-the-source-files-where-they-are/70779582?noredirect=1#comment125148566_70779582):

> This modifies all existing commit ids.
> If you have your history shared, all others need to re-clone.

This is true for any rebase or filter operations (`git filter-branch`, `git filter-repo`, `BFG`, ...): a `git push --force` or `git push --mirror` is often implied at the end.
And that does mean communicating to any contributor the new state of that repository, for them to clone it again.

Comment: Note that this modifies all existing commit ids. If you have your history shared, all others need to re-clone.

Comment: @knittl Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.