# Just set a dev server up, now want to hook my bare repo on my production server to deploy using git

Tags: git, deployment, repository

So I created on my production server a bare repo, and on my client machine I am committing and pushing to the `master` branch within it. This is fine and dandy and I setup a hook to automatically deploy from the bare repo, but I just set up a dev server.

Now I want to work locally and push everything to my dev server, and from there (if things look good and aren't broken) I want to be able to deploy it to my production server.

What are the steps I need to take to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring to a production server is generally hard, because:

- the access is quite limited and controlled
- you need to be extra sure that you did copied everything you need (ie no data corruption)

What you can do is updating on your dev server a bundle of your repo. Or, if you don't have git on your server, at least an archive.
Both options are detailed in "[backing up project which uses git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046918/backing-up-project-which-uses-git/2047141#2047141)".

The idea is to:

- transfer only *one* file
- `git clone` (if you transfer a bundle) or simply uncompress (if you transfer an archive)