# Best way to synchronize 2 git repos

Tags: git

What would be the best way of synchronizing two repos(one being a mirror) and keep it updated

Orignal step

```
$ git clone --mirror git@example.com/ori.git
$ cd upstream-repository.git
$ git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

Based on  Cronjob

```
$ cd upstream-repository.git
$ git remote update
$ git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

Does it make sense ?

Comment: why not rsync ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense ?

It depends on your remote server.
If you are pushing to the *same* git repo server, you could have a local  backup repo with a regular pull from another local repo of that server.

Regarding your `git remote update`, see "[Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/6309)": you can check if you have received any commit at all; if not, not need to push.

If you are pushing to another server which might not be listening for git queries, then you would use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle), which means transferring only *one* file (as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047141/6309))

.